# PHP select with 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I populate a select box like this

```
foreach ( $prov->getLicences() as $licence ) {
    echo '<option value="' . $licence['id'] . '">' . $licence['licence'] . '</option>';
}
```

This select box is for editing an existing db entry, so i can grab the already selected licences with this.

```
$prov->getSubscriberLicences($id)
```

This will return an array of id's, how do i check these id's against the available values in the select box above.

If they match i want to add the `selected` tag to the option value.

```
 echo '<option selected  value="' . $licence['id'] . '">' . $licence['licence'] . '</option>';
```

**EDIT:**

Please be aware `$prov->getSubscriberLicences($id)` returns an array of multiple ids
here is a var dump

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" } }
```

looks like its multidementional

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP multi dimensional array search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As very minimum info is given i can think of this only, Just try this-

```
$selected = (in_array($licence['id'],$prov->getSubscriberLicences($id)) ? "select" : "");

echo '<option '.$selected.'  value="' . $licence['id'] . '">' . $licence['licence'] . '</option>';
```

Comment: on which line your are getting?

Comment: @VinceLowe: my bad, updated first line, did not close the bracket.

Comment: i spotted it, still non are showing as selected.. is it because $licence['id'] is a value and not array?