# Search value in array object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, arrayobject

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ADADCD] =>       
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ADADCD] => ?     
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ADADCD] => HOSP1 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ADADCD] => HOSP2 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ADADCD] => H1    
        )

)
```

We have an array like this ,I want to search a specific value like **HOSP2**,What is the process to get the value at index.

Comment: Always the array index would be 1. If you wanna search multiple array like this, update your question with the definition.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search ?

Answer (score 3):

Just try with [`array_search`](http://php.net/array_search)

```
$key = array_search(array('ADADCD' => 'HOSP1'), $inputArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

Loop trough the array and return the index on which you find the value you are looking for.

```
$searchIndex = -1;
foreach ( $yourArray as $k => $v ) {
  if ( $v['ADADCD'] == 'search value' ) {
    $searchIndex = $k;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use a combination of [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

So, first looping through all the indices of the array using `foreach()`.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $subarray)
   if (in_array($string, $subarray))
       return $key;
```

So, now for an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ADADCD] =>       
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ADADCD] => ?     
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ADADCD] => HOSP1 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ADADCD] => HOSP2 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ADADCD] => H1    
        )
)
```

#### Output

```
2
```

#### Fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/t6b-g9r

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
$array = your array;
$key = array_search('HOSP2', $array);
echo $key;
?>
```

Output: ADADCD

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: Please check, what is the output needed by the OP.