# Search an Array for a Specific Value using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, search

I am trying to search an array for a given value. Once I find this value, I need the `array key` value to access other information in the array. Here is the array I need to search:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(20) {
    ["FirstName"]=>
    string(7) "Person1"
    ["LastName"]=>
    string(7) "Person1"
    ["UserId"]=>
    int(5632414)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(20) {
     ["FirstName"]=>
    string(7) "Person2"
    ["LastName"]=>
    string(7) "Person2"
    ["UserId"]=>
    int(5632414)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(20) {
     ["FirstName"]=>
    string(7) "Person3"
    ["LastName"]=>
    string(7) "Person3"
    ["UserId"]=>
    int(5632414)
  }
}
```

I am searching the array for a specific UserId. I have tried several bits of code but none seem to work. All I get is a blank screen when I run the script. Here is my most current code:

```
$array = json_decode($output);

for ($x = 0; $x <= count($array); $x++) {
    $key = array_search('5632414', $array);
    echo $key;
}
```

Comment: `$array = json_decode($output);` gives an object, not an array. You need to pass `true` as the second parameter to make it one. `$array = json_decode($output, true);`

Comment: It should be `$x < count($array)`, or you'll miss the last element.

Comment: Actually, that should be "or you'll go past the last element".

Comment: This question has already been [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_search` can only be used with one-dimensional arrays. In your case, you're not looking for a string in the top-level array, it's the value of one of the associative sub-arrays.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $subarray) {
    if ($subarray['UserId'] == 5632414) {
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the `var_dump` output you posted, it looks like you could do something like:

```
$array = json_decode($output);

for ($x = 0; $x < count($array); $x++) {
    if ( $array[ x ][ "UserId" ] === $the_value_I_am_looking_for )
    {
        //Then do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function findIn($find, $inArray){
  foreach($inArray as $a){
    foreach($a as $i => $v){
      if($v === $find){
        return $i;
      }
    }
  }
}
```