# Access specific row in mysql recordset

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table with options that looks like this

[image: Database records]

I do a `SELECT * FROM options` and load all records into a recordset.

How do I then access just the optionValue of optionName = SMSactive

**[EDIT]**

Yes, I could do `SELECT * FROM options WHERE optionName ='SMSactive'` - I know that.

But as I said, since I have a recordset with a bunch of rows in it (from the SELECT), I want to pull a specific row where optionName = SMSactive

**[EDIT]**
If you are using PHP >= 5.5 you can use array_column() http://php.net/array_column

But if not, the question has already been asked and answered here [PHP multidimensional array search by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search)

Comment: show your select stament

Comment: This question, as it stands, is unclear; please consider putting in more effort to make sure everyone understands the exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

To access to all records with optionName = SMSactive the SQL should be:

```
SELECT * FROM `TableName` WHERE `optionName` = 'SMSactive'
```

if your array result from the query is something like this:

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'optionName' => 'lala0',
        'optionDescription' => 'lala01',
        'optionValue' => 'lala03',
    ),
    1 => array(
        'optionName' => 'lala1',
        'optionDescription' => 'ala2',
        'optionValue' => 'SMSactive',
    )
);
```

You can grab who has `'optionValue' => 'SMSactive',` by this way

```
foreach ($array as $key) {
    if ($key['optionValue'] == 'SMSactive') {
        $filtered[]=$key;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($filtered);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Side Note:** If the array is very large you have to be careful with the memory...it's advisable just get from the db what you are using in the moment...IMO

Comment: Modified from the movie Dodgeball - If you can do a write a SELECT statement, you can write a WHERE clause.

Comment: maybe I didn't make myself clear.  I already do SELECT * FROM options.  I have all rows in the array.  Now I just want to grab one of them without doing another call to the database.

Comment: @EmilioGort it's a movie reference. You have to be familiar with the movie to understand what I wrote.

Comment: If that is how you want to phrase it, yes, I need to find that option in the multi dimensional array.

Comment: Thanks Emilio and it is correct but I knew how to do that.  I was hoping there might be a way to search the array directly.  I am using PHP < 5.5 or I could use array_column.  In fact, this is a more elegant way of doing it using your technique  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search

Comment: the another way I see is using array filter with  callback function but at the end is the same