# In PHP can I use a variable in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array

I want to search a multidimensional Array for a specific field, then reference that variable in an Array. I have used one Array for this example:

```
$cars = array
(
array("Volvo",$vr,96),
array("BMW",60,59),
array("Toyota",110,100)
);

$vr=$cars[1][2];
echo $cars[0][1];
```

How do I do that?

Or this?

```
$cars = array
(
array("Volvo",10,96),
array("BMW",60,59),
array("Toyota",110,100)
);


$graph = array
(
array("sept", $cars[0][1]),
array("oct", 20),
array("nov", 35)
);
```

Comment: What you're asking is not clear. Please elaborate. What kind of search are you performing on what source and what for?

Comment: The above is just a more straightforward version of what I want to do. I want to search a multidimensional Array $cars[0][1] and use that number in a another multidimensional Array either as a variable or directly.

Comment: In the 2nd example the 2nd Array builds a graph using phplot

Comment: does that `$vr=$cars[1][2];` in same location( `SAME KEY` ) in your array ?

Comment: I guess the question really is can you use a variable in a multidimensional Array?

Comment: @samitha not sure what you mean? If the above examples are possible, then my actual code should be fine. Do you know if a variable can be used in a multidimensional Array? Cuz I reckon thats the bones of it

Comment: may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search

Comment: I dont think so from what I understand. I'm accessing a value in a multi Array then using that value in another multi Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes is the answer. I know it must seem like a very newbie question but hopefully this will hep someone in the future:

```
$cars1 = array
(
array("Volvo",3,96),
array("BMW",60,59),
array("Toyota",110,100),

);

$vr=$cars1[1][1];

$cars = array
(
array("Volvo",$vr,96),
array("BMW",60,59),
array("Toyota",110,100),

);

echo $cars[0][1];
```

Correct me if I am wrong but I guess it has something to do with the order of the PHP. The Array needed the variable before the Array was made.