# php- multidimensional array search

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional countries array containing :

- code -> Country Code
- name - > Country Name
- flag -> CSS sprite flag class

The needle is a **countryCode** and haystack the **$countriesArray**. How would you search for a string(countryCode) and return the corresponding name and flag. Is this array badly constructed?.

**Array**

```
$CountriesArray = array(array( code => "bj", 
                               name => "Benin",
                               flag => "flag flag-bj"
                            ),

                        array( code => "bw", 
                               name => "Botswana",
                               flag => "flag flag-bw"
                            ),

                        array( code => "cg", 
                               name => "Congo",
                               flag => "flag flag-cg"
                             )
  ect....

  );
```

**ANSWER -Array format updated where the key is the countryCode**

```
$CountriesArray = array(  array( bj => array( name=> "Benin", flag => "flag flag-bj" )), 
                          array( bw => array( name=> "Botswana", flag => "flag flag-bw" )),
                          array( cg => array( name=> "Congo", flag => "flag flag-cg" ))
                   );
```

**Search array where $n = needle**

```
function multiDimenArraySearch($n,$h){
foreach($h as $key => $value){
if($key == $n) return $value;
  }
}

$n = "bj";
$search = multiDimenArraySearch($n,$CountriesArray);

$name = $search[$n]["name"]; //outputs name
$flag = $search[$n]["flag"]; // outputs flag class
```

Comment: A meaningful key would make it better (for instance... `countryCode`), as it stands just looping in a `foreach` & checking for if `$currentvalue['code'] == $countryCode` is about as good as it gets, no need to make it more elaborate.

Comment: you mean like $CountriesArray = array(bj=>array(name=>"Benin",flag=>"flag flag-bj"),array(bw=>array(name=>"Botswana" ect...

Comment: Yep, that would make it work a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($countriesArray); $i++){
    if($countriesArray[$i]["code"] == "cg"){
        return $countriesArray[$i]["name"];
    }
}
```

this should work

foreach version:

```
foreach($countriesArray as $country){
    if($country["code"] == "cg"){
        ...
    }
}
```

Example function:

```
function multiDimenArraySearch($n,$h){
    foreach($h as $arr){
        if($arr['code'] == $n){
            return $arr;
        }
    }
}

$search = multiDimenArraySearch("cg",$countriesArray);
$name = $search["name"];
```

For search value is array key:

```
foreach($h as $key => $value){
    if($key == "cg") return $value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nasaorc, your foreach version works fine. If anyone is wondering the same, please read above Wrikken recommendation.

Comment: Updated answer for search array key

Comment: Wait what? If we have the key we just `return $array[$key];`, why would we ever need a `for` loop there?

Answer (score 1):

Same question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search), basically you just have to loop through all the different arrays.  In the example below $return_val will be the array of the country.

```
$search_term = 'cg';
foreach($countriesArray as $c_info){
   if($c_info['code']==$search_term){
      $return_val = $c_info;
   }
}
```