# PHP - Find key in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there any predefined PHP function to find a key in a multi dimensional array?

In the below example - there is a variable name 'rose' and I need to get the key of the array by using the variable name. 
The result of the key is "flower".

```
$array = array (
                    'fruits' => array (
                                            'mango',
                                            'cherry'
                                    ),
                    'flowers' => array (
                                            'rose'
                                    )
            );
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search

Comment: No, there's no single function that will do it for you.

Comment: Are the groups mutually exclusive? In other words, can a term appear in multiple groups and do you need to find all applicable groups?

Comment: Yes they are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop it up using a `foreach`

```
$keyword='mango';
foreach($array as $k=>$arr)
{
    if(in_array($keyword,$arr))
    {
        echo $k;break;// "prints" fruits
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/130017)

Comment: @Jeff, Nah, did you check the demo ?

Comment: Just deleted my comment when I realized my mistake! Sorry.