# How to compare the elements in 2D array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I am having an array like this...

```
array(
   array(
      1, 3
   ),
   array(
      4, 6, 8
   ),
   array(
      2, 3, 5, 1
   )
)
```

Now i want to compare first element with all the element in the second row.means I want to compare 1 with 4,6 and 8.Then with 3rd row elements like 1 with 2,3,5 and 1.Likewise i want to compare

1 is exist totally two times in the given array....So the variable count1=2....likewise 3 is exist 2 times so count2=2...8 is exist only one time so count8=1....like this...

Kindly help me to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: are these different arrays or just one array?

Comment: And what should happen after all those comparisons?

Comment: what comparision you want `==` or `>=` or what?

Comment: I want to check the same element exist or not....

Comment: What of the second element of the first row? And what should happen if you find an existing element in any of the other rows?

Comment: If that element exist,I want to increase the count by 2...because that element exist for 2 times....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just after a frequency table, you can flatten it with [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge) and use [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/array_count_values) to get a tally:

```
print_r(array_count_values(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array)));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 1
    [6] => 1
    [8] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [5] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search)

Or Example

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Use

```
$b = array(array("Mac", "NT"), array("Irix", "Linux"));
echo in_array_r("Irix", $b) ? 'found' : 'not found';
```

Comment: How to achieve this in 2d array???