# Search Array Value and return row in php

Tags: php, arrays, function, search

Can't find quite the right answer so hope someone can help. Basically want to Search [VIN] value and if matched then return [MEDIAID] or row.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CLIENTID] => GALLEY
            [VIN] => WBAFDEG2317MCB73388
            [MEDIAID] => 10011020061817-galley_082114-SDvcl-140880481613056500
            [DEALERNAME] => Demo
            [PUBLISHON] => 2014-08-28
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [CLIENTID] => GALLEY
            [VIN] => WAULC68E74A053WE251
            [MEDIAID] => 10011020061817-galley_082114-SDvcl-140880482109709900
            [DEALERNAME] => Demo
            [PUBLISHON] => 2014-08-26
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [CLIENTID] => GALLEY
            [VIN] => WAULC68E74A053WE251
            [MEDIAID] => 10011020061817-galley_082114-SDvcl-140880482109709900
            [PUBLISHON] => 2014-08-26
        )
)
```

I need do this in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function structure copied from this [already answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search), and I just made a few changes to make it work for your application:

```
function searchForId($id, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val['VIN'] === $id) {
           return $val['MEDIAID'];
       }
   }
   return null;
}

$array = array(
  0=> array(
    'CLIENTID' => 'GALLEY',
    'VIN' => 'WBAFDEG2317MCB73388',
    'MEDIAID' => '10011020061817-galley_082114-SDvcl-140880481613056500',
    'DEALERNAME' => 'Demo',
    'PUBLISHON' => '2014-08-28'
    ),
  1=> array(
    'CLIENTID' => 'GALLEY',
    'VIN' => 'WAULC68E74A053WE251',
    'MEDIAID' => '10011020061817-galley_082114-SDvcl-140880482109709900',
    'DEALERNAME' => 'Demo',
    'PUBLISHON' => '2014-08-26'
    ),
  2=> array(
    'CLIENTID' => 'GALLEY',
    'VIN' => 'WAULC68E74A053WE251',
    'MEDIAID' => '10011020061817-galley_082114-SDvcl-140880482109709900',
    'DEALERNAME' => 'Demo',
    'PUBLISHON' => '2014-08-26'
    ),    
  );

$search = searchForId('WAULC68E74A053WE251', $array);

var_dump($search);
```

Result:

```
string(53) "10011020061817-galley_082114-SDvcl-140880482109709900"
```

See [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/810734a42e8cf59f4042f8156d524b71c3b19f38)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the code. but I am getting error. my system generates array without Comma (,) Semicolon (;).

Comment: Can you specify more? What system? How is system generating arrays?

Comment: I am generating array from csv using php csv parser.

Comment: my code generating array like my example without single quote, comma and semicolon. your code not working for my array.

Comment: It is `print_r()` output, so you should have stored array in variable too. Can you post your code what is outputing this array?

Comment: Hi, working fine now. I dont know what was the issue before. any way Thanks for the help. :)