# Remove submenu page "customize.php" in WordPress 4.0

Tags: wordpress

When I was running WP 3.9.2 I was able to use the following code to remove the Customize menu item from Appearance in the admin menu.

```
function remove_customize() {
  remove_submenu_page('themes.php', 'customize.php');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'remove_customize', 999);
```

Once I updated to 4.0 this is no longer working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Edit: Updated for WordPress 4.9+ and increased compatibility with PHP <= 5.4

WordPress core doesn't offer a hook to natively [disable the theme customizer](https://wptavern.com/filter-to-disable-the-customizer-shot-down-on-wordpress-trac), but there *is a clever and elegant way* to remove the “Customize” link from the Appearance menu by altering the global `$submenu` variable:

```php
/**
 * Remove Admin Menu Link to Theme Customizer
 */
add_action( 'admin_menu', function () {
    global $submenu;

    if ( isset( $submenu[ 'themes.php' ] ) ) {
        foreach ( $submenu[ 'themes.php' ] as $index => $menu_item ) {
            if ( in_array( array( 'Customize', 'Customizer', 'customize' ), $menu_item ) ) {
                unset( $submenu[ 'themes.php' ][ $index ] );
            }
        }
    }
});
```

While other code samples here and elsewhere irresponsibly rely on specific numeric indexes of the global **$submenu** variable (e.g. `$submenu['themes.php'][6][0]`, ...), this method intelligently traverses through the hierarchy so it should be compatible with older (3.x) and newer versions of WordPress (4.x) alike.

Comment: I'm working with WP 8.4. The check on 'Customize' does dot work here, i had to change it into 'Customizer'.

Comment: Does not work for me in WP 4.8 (also not if 'Customize' is changed to 'Customizer'. @Ov3rfly's answer below worked.

Comment: @nachtigall I updated the answer to reflect current usage with WordPress 4.8+ and PHP 5.x+.

Comment: Using `in_array` with an array for the "needle" isn't working for me. When I changed the "needle" to a string, it worked i.e. `in_array(  'customize', $menu_item )`.

Comment: For some reason, the array for the "needle" isn't working for me. You can keep the same functionality by adjusting the if statement like so `if ( in_array( 'Customize', $menu_item, true ) || in_array( 'Customizer', $menu_item, true ) || in_array( 'customize', $menu_item, true )) { }`.

Answer (score 18):

This works with WordPress 4.1 and 4.0 and 3.x here:

*Edit:* Adjusted for WordPress 4.1 compatibility:

```
function remove_customize() {
    $customize_url_arr = array();
    $customize_url_arr[] = 'customize.php'; // 3.x
    $customize_url = add_query_arg( 'return', urlencode( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ), 'customize.php' );
    $customize_url_arr[] = $customize_url; // 4.0 & 4.1
    if ( current_theme_supports( 'custom-header' ) && current_user_can( 'customize') ) {
        $customize_url_arr[] = add_query_arg( 'autofocus[control]', 'header_image', $customize_url ); // 4.1
        $customize_url_arr[] = 'custom-header'; // 4.0
    }
    if ( current_theme_supports( 'custom-background' ) && current_user_can( 'customize') ) {
        $customize_url_arr[] = add_query_arg( 'autofocus[control]', 'background_image', $customize_url ); // 4.1
        $customize_url_arr[] = 'custom-background'; // 4.0
    }
    foreach ( $customize_url_arr as $customize_url ) {
        remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', $customize_url );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_customize', 999 );
```

Comment: It looks like @chrisphilton 's answer is a lot more succinct.

Comment: Mostly works! But doesn't remove the custom background in 4.9.  I will try it in 4.8 later.

Comment: This is the only solution on this page that worked for me.  Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17):

Answer should be:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', function () {
global $submenu;
if ( isset( $submenu[ 'themes.php' ] ) ) {
    foreach ( $submenu[ 'themes.php' ] as $index => $menu_item ) {
        foreach ($menu_item as $value) {
            if (strpos($value,'customize') !== false) {
                unset( $submenu[ 'themes.php' ][ $index ] );
            }
        }
    }
}
});
```

The way rjb used an array as the needle in in_array() in the accepted answer doesn't work. Check out why [in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#example-6163). I replaced in_array with another foreach that loops through the $menu_item arrays and looks for 'customize' as part of the value.

Works for me with WordPress 4.9.6

Comment: +1000. This should be the accepted answer, correcting an obvious PHP error no-one else spotted for six months...

Comment: ✓ Works in 5.0.3

Comment: ✓ Works in 5.1.1

Comment: ✓ Works in 6.2.2

Answer (score 8):

You can directly modify the `$submenus` global like so:

```
global $submenu;
unset($submenu['themes.php'][6]); // Customize link
```

I'm using this in the same function, hooked into `admin_menu`, as I use to unset other admin items and it seems to be working fine

```
function as_remove_menus () {
       remove_menu_page('upload.php'); //hide Media
       remove_menu_page('link-manager.php'); //hide links
       remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php', 'edit-tags.php' ); //hide tags
       global $submenu;
        // Appearance Menu
        unset($submenu['themes.php'][6]); // Customize
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'as_remove_menus');
```

Comment: Is there any worry about the index of the Appearance menu in that array changing in future releases?

Comment: @isabisa Initially I thought you cold just use `array_search` but since it is a multidimensional array, you could use an approach like described in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search).

Answer (score 6):

You can in fact use `remove_submenu_page` to remove the theme submenu option from the admin screen. The trick is that the url must match what is being exactly linked in the admin for that function to work.

```
function remove_admin_menus() {

    remove_submenu_page( 
        'themes.php', 
        'customize.php?return=' . 
            urlencode( str_replace( get_bloginfo('url'), "", get_admin_url() ) ) . 
            'themes.php' );

}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_admin_menus' );
```

I have programmatically determined the admin url in the case that you aren't simply using '/wp-admin'. @isabisa This will also avoid breaking in the future if the index of the menu item ever changes.

I'm using this in WP 4.0 and it works great!

Comment: A nice succinct answer, that doesn't need to call a global! This is especially useful when you have a function being used to remove other menu/submenu items.

Answer (score 5):

Removing the menu is only a halfway solution, since it doesn't completely disable the customizer. In order to fully and securely disable the customizer (and also remove the menu), you need to remove the customizer permission from all users. Something like this would do it:

```
add_filter('map_meta_cap', function($caps, $cap, $user_id, $args) {
    if ('customize' == $cap) return ['do_not_allow'];
    return $caps;
}, 10, 4);
```

Comment: This solution completely removed the Customizer link from the admin bar and the admin panel Appearance menu using v5.1.8. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

WordPress >= 4.9.8

```
add_action('admin_menu', function () {
  $request = urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  remove_submenu_page('themes.php', 'customize.php?return='. $request);
}, 999);
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer by @rjb didn't work for my spanish wordpress, but just changing the `Customize` to `customize` did the trick.

```
/**
 * Remove Admin Menu Link to Theme Customizer
 */
add_action( 'admin_menu', function () {
    global $submenu;

    if ( isset( $submenu[ 'themes.php' ] ) ) {
        foreach ( $submenu[ 'themes.php' ] as $index => $menu_item ) {
            if ( in_array( 'customize', $menu_item ) ) {
                unset( $submenu[ 'themes.php' ][ $index ] );
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Works in wordpres 5.***

Removing Customize from Wordpress Admin you need to remove from the sidebar and from the top bar in front end as well

**From the Sidebar Menu**

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_customize' );

function remove_customize() {
    global $submenu;
    if ( isset( $submenu[ 'themes.php' ] ) ) {
        foreach ( $submenu[ 'themes.php' ] as $index => $menu_item ) {
            if(in_array('Customize', $menu_item) || in_array('Customizer', $menu_item) || in_array('customize', $menu_item))
            {
                unset( $submenu[ 'themes.php' ][ $index ] );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**From Admin bar in top (In The front End)**

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_customize_menu_bar', 999 );

function remove_customize_menu_bar( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'customize' );
}
```

This will completely disable the customize option :)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Little sidenote: it does not remove the customizer completely as there are still buttons directing to it from Theme's.

Answer (score 1):

### For WordPress 5

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', function() {
    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'customize.php?return=' . urlencode($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
}, 999 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 'admin_init' in 'admin_menu'

Answer (score 0):

[@bash88 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50912719/2349886) and [@Emanuel A. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44379695/2349886) works but if you want also remove buttons (blue customize buttons) from themes page answer should be:

Tested WordPress 5.0.3

```
/**
 * Remove customize links from admin panel.
 */
function admin_remove_customize_links() {
    echo '<style>.hide-if-no-customize { display: none !important; }</style>';
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'admin_remove_customize_links' );
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update of the approved response (Wordpress 5)

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'rompiot_remove_customize' );

/**
 * Remove Admin Menu Link to Theme Customizer
 */
public function rompiot_remove_customize()
{
    global $submenu;

    if (isset($submenu['themes.php'])) {
        
        foreach ($submenu['themes.php'] as $index => $array_menu_item) {

            foreach ($array_menu_item as $key => $menu_item) {
                if (in_array($menu_item, ['Customize', 'Customizer', 'customize'])) {
                    unset($submenu['themes.php'][$index]);
                }
            }                

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**FUNCTIONING CODE AS OF WORDPRESS 5.7+, AUGUST 2021**

I needed to customize the WP admin bar for a large WP site we are working on (text was running off the admin bar when resizing). I tried literally every snippet of code from all the previous answers to this question; unfortunately none worked for me. This code I found off Google did, so I wanted to share with others (goes in your functions.php):

```
/**
 * This function removes items from the WP admin bar. If it gets too cluttered,
 * things will run off the screen and look bad.
 * @param object $wp_admin_bar representing the WP admin bar.
 */
function remove_from_admin_bar($wp_admin_bar) {
    // WordPress Core Items (uncomment to remove)
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('updates');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('comments');
    //wp_admin_bar->remove_node('new-content');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('wp-logo');
    //$wp_admin_bar->remove_node('site-name');
    //$wp_admin_bar->remove_node('my-account');
    //$wp_admin_bar->remove_node('search');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('customize');
}

add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'remove_from_admin_bar', 999);
```

I think a great start is to remove the comments, updates, and WP icon. Custom plugins can be disabled here, too. The 999 indicates when the hook will fire off later. You can wrap elements in the `is_admin()` function if you want to hide or show different links on the front end vs. the WP admin.