# Match two arrays based on dates

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I try to match to arrays based on the dates. The first array is generated by a function (getDateRange), the second array comes from my Wordpress database.

```
function getDateRange($startDate, $endDate, $format="Y-m-d")
    {
        //Create output variable
        $datesArray = array();
        //Calculate number of days in the range
        $total_days = round(abs(strtotime($endDate) - strtotime($startDate)) / 86400, 0) + 1;
        if($total_days<0) { return false; }
        //Populate array of weekdays and counts
        for($day=0; $day<$total_days; $day++)
        {
            $datesArray[] = date($format, strtotime("{$startDate} + {$day} days"));
        }
        //Return results array
        return $datesArray;
    }


$sql = "SELECT date(datetime) AS date, SUM(amount) as amount FROM sales GROUP BY 1";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);

// Generate the date range 
$dateRange = getDateRange('2014-10-01', '2014-10-06');

foreach($dateRange as $date) {
 echo $date . ' | ';

    if (array_key_exists($date, $results)) {
    echo 'OK';

    } else {
     echo '0';   
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

With the code above I don't get matching values:

```
2014-10-01 | 0
2014-10-02 | 0
2014-10-03 | 0
2014-10-04 | 0
2014-10-05 | 0
2014-10-06 | 0
```

The desired result is:

```
2014-10-01 | 0
2014-10-02 | 0
2014-10-03 | OK
2014-10-04 | 0
2014-10-05 | OK
2014-10-06 | 0
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($results)` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ARRAY_A - result will be output as an numerically indexed array of associative arrays, using column names as keys

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results#SELECT_Generic_Results)

So `array_key_exists` will search the date in the keys of `$results` array, which has only numeric keys.

You could implement a search function for multidimensional arrays instead of `array_key_exists`

```
function searchForDate($date, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        if ($val['date'] === $date) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

modified from: [PHP multidimensional array search by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the right answer relies on how does your `$results` array looks like...

```
 Array ( [0] => 2014-10-01 [1] => 2014-10-02 [2] => 2014-10-03 [3] => 2014-10-04 [4] => 2014-10-05 [5] => 2014-10-06 )
```

that, is your `$dateRange` array. Normally, upon foreach, you will get each date as a simple string, so, in turn, your `$date` var will be: 
 
2014-10-01 
2014-10-02 
2014-10-03 
2014-10-04 
2014-10-05 
2014-10-06

And those are the values used in `if (array_key_exists($date, $results)) {}`. This means, that, using this scenario, your `$results` array must have dates as keys, so it should look something like: 
`Array ( [2014-10-03] => 'foo'  [2014-10-06] => 'bar' )`

After this, you will definitely have hits.
But again, without a dump of `$results` I cannot guarantee that this is what you need.

Hope it helps!

Keep on coding!

Ares.