# PHP: Find string in Multi-dimensional array or return empty array keys?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a multi-dimensional array `$rows` which return the result like below; I have created queries based on array_keys. Now the problem I am facing is $rows may or may not return some of the rows if there is no vacant beds and all my queries goes for a toss.

I have tried to use `in_array` function, but it appears this doens't work with multi-dimensional array.

```
array (size=6)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'room_category' => string 'MALE GENERAL WARD' (length=17)
          'vacant_beds' => string 'MG-5' (length=4)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'room_category' => string 'FEMALE GENERAL WARD' (length=19)
          'vacant_beds' => string 'FG-2,FG-3,FG-4' (length=14)
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          'room_category' => string 'MOTHER CHILD WARD' (length=17)
          'vacant_beds' => string 'MC-1,MC-3,MC-4' (length=14)
      3 => 
        array (size=2)
          'room_category' => string 'NICU' (length=4)
          'vacant_beds' => string 'NICU-8,NICU-4,NICU-5,NICU-6,NICU-1,NICU-7,NICU-2' (length=48)
      4 => 
        array (size=2)
          'room_category' => string 'CLASSIC' (length=7)
          'vacant_beds' => string 'CL-9,CL-4,CL-5,CL-7,CL-8' (length=24)
      5 => 
        array (size=2)
          'room_category' => string 'DELUXE' (length=6)
          'vacant_beds' => string 'DLX-6,DLX-3,DLX-4,DLX-5' (length=23)
```

What approach I should take or ensure that it returns a row even if a specific ward is not vacant.

My code for $rows is like this:

```
select `rct`.`room_category` AS `room_category`,
    group_concat(`rn`.`room_name` separator ',') AS `vacant_beds` 
    from ((`room_name` `rn` join `room_category` 
    `rct` on((`rn`.`room_category` = `rct`.`id`))) 
    left join `patient_detail` `pd` on(((`rn`.`id` = `pd`.`bed_type`) 
    and (isnull(`pd`.`discharge_date`) or (now() between `pd`.`admission_date` and `pd`.`discharge_date`))))) 
    where isnull(`pd`.`id`) group by `rn`.`room_category`
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP multi dimensional array search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search)

Comment: Hi Marc - Question heading may be duplicate, but I have asked for additional solutions like whether I can return array keys with empty values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JOIN to the empty beds query is leaving out empty values. I suggest you use a subquery to generate a complete list of `room_category` values.

```
            select distinct room_category
              from room_category
```

Then I suggest you LEFT JOIN that subquery into the rest of your query, and using its value to group by. That will end up looking something like this:

```
select a.room_category, 
       group_concat(b.room_name ORDER BY b.room_name) vacancies
  from (select distinct id, room_category from room_category) a
  left join 
       (select rct.room_category AS room_category,
               rn.room_name 
          from room_category rct  
          left join room_name rn on rn.room_category = rct.id
          left join patient_detail pd on rn.id = pd.bed_type
                 and (isnull(pd.discharge_date) or now() 
                      between pd.admission_date and pd.discharge_date)
         where isnull(pd.id) 
         order by rct.room_category, rn.room_name
    ) b on a.room_category=b.room_category
group by a.room_category
order by a.room_category
```

Comment: Hi Ollie Jones I tried ur suggestion, but it returns just a single `room_category` group and beds in that group.

Comment: I wish I could debug the query for you, but only you have your data.

Comment: Hi Olli Jones - I am ready to give access to my system if you are so nice to do it for me.

Comment: OK. I could do that for you. See my profile for contact info.

Comment: I have sent the access ID & password to ur email for Team Viewer