# Finding value within Multi-dimensional Array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to match today's date to the dates stored in an array. I am nearly there, but not quite.

If a match is found, I want to build a link, if not, do nothing.

The problem is that the match isn't what is expected.
ie: For testing purposes, if I change one of the arrays to match today's date ( 11-08 ) it doesn't pull out the correct Festival name.

Any help greatly appreciated. I originally tried to adapt this post :- 
[PHP multidimensional array search by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search/24527099#24527099)

```
$festivals = array (
1  => array(
        'festivalname' => 'FestivalOne',
        'eventname'    => 'Red',
        'link'         => 'red',
        'date'         => '01-05',
        ),
2 => array(
        'festivalname' => 'FestivalTwo',
        'eventname'    => 'Yellow',
        'link'         => 'yellow',
        'date'         => '02-02',
        ),
3 => array(
        'festivalname' => 'FestivalThree',
        'eventname'    => 'Blue',
        'link'         => 'blue',
        'date'         => '02-08',
        ),
4  => array(
        'festivalname' => 'FestivalFour',
        'eventname'    => 'Green',
        'link'         => 'green',
        'date'         => '31-10',
        )
);

$today = gmdate("j-m");
$key = array_search($today, array_column($festivals, 'date'));
$keys = array_keys(array_column($festivals, 'date'), $today);


if ( $today == $festivals[$key]['link'] )  {

echo '<a href="http://example.com/festivals/'.$festivals[$key]['link'].'"   title="Festival : '.$festivals[$key]['festivalname'].'">'.$festivals[$key]['festivalname'].'</a>';
```

};

Comment: I think the answer is here http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: It's the matching that doesn't work properly

Comment: Please edit the question explaining what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $festivals = array (
1  => array(
        'festivalname' => 'FestivalOne',
        'eventname'    => 'Red',
        'link'         => 'red',
        'date'         => '01-05',
        ),
2 => array(
        'festivalname' => 'FestivalTwo',
        'eventname'    => 'Yellow',
        'link'         => 'yellow',
        'date'         => '02-02',
        ),
3 => array(
        'festivalname' => 'FestivalThree',
        'eventname'    => 'Blue',
        'link'         => 'blue',
        'date'         => '02-08',
        ),
4  => array(
        'festivalname' => 'FestivalFour',
        'eventname'    => 'Green',
        'link'         => 'green',
        'date'         => '31-10',
        )
);

$today = gmdate("j-m");

foreach($festivals as $item) {


if ( $today == $item['date'] )  {

echo '<a href="http://example.com/festivals/'.$item['link'].'"   title="Festival : '.$item['festivalname'].'">'.$item['festivalname'].'</a>';
 }

}


?>
```