# array_search() in Session Array

Tags: php

I tried to use the function `array_search` but can't get it work..

I got a php session with an array.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
    array(6) {
       ["ProductId"]=>string(2) "34"
       ["ProductName"]=>string(9) "Best ever"
       ["ProductPrice"]=>string(6) "453.00"
       ["ProductColor"]=>string(4) "Blue"
       ["ProductSize"]=>string(1) "S"
       ["Image"]=>string(36) "d12f95895c9130da8e52a7ff5b9216c9.png"
    }
 [1]=>
    array(6) {
       ["ProductId"]=>string(2) "33"
       ["ProductName"]=>string(5) "Vespa"
       ["ProductPrice"]=>string(7) "1789.00"
       ["ProductColor"]=>string(4) "Blue"
       ["ProductSize"]=>string(1) "S"
       ["Image"]=>string(36) "678e25ea94a7fa94bc6fa427ff29bc6c.png"
    }
```

now I do an `array_search()`

```
session_start();
include '_sqlclean.php';
(isset($_POST['product_id'])) ? $p_id = clean_string_save($_POST['product_id']) : $p_id = 0;
$array = $_SESSION['wishList'];

$key = array_search($p_id, $array);
```

if I do a

```
var_dump($_SESSION['wishList']);
```

I got what I showed you above.
But I always got the message "Key not found"

Why ?? What's my mistake ?
I tried already to do

```
$p_id = "34" // for try
$p_id = intval(34); // for try also
$key = array_search("34", $_SESSION['wishList']); // to see if it works
```

but nothing worked.. :(
Thanks in advance

Comment: $array[index]['associative_index_name'] you are using a vector, you need to access ROOT and then CHILD.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP multi dimensional array search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_search` will not work for multidimensional `array`s. Rather this might work -

```
$key = array_search($p_id, array_column($array, 'ProductId'));
```

This will extract all the `ProductId` from that `array` then do the search.

Comment: Thanks works perfectly.. 2hours I've been searching before posting... :( and thanks for the Tips !! I didn't know that..

Comment: One more thing.. so to unset() "delete the row after" I need to do: 
    unset($_SESSION['wishList'][$key]);
Or is there something special to do because it's a multidimensional array ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with alternative for `array_search()`.For example:

```
function searchForId($id, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
      if ($val['uid'] === $id) {
        return $key;
    }
  }
 return null;
}
```

**OR**

```
$key = array_search($p_id, array_column($array, 'ProductId'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Aparently you are mistyping the `variable` (key) name

in the `array` it is 
    ProductId
and in your code it is
    Product_Id

Answer (score 0):

It happen cause you search into outer array, which contains only `[0]` and `[1]` keys.

Try to use

```
$key = array_search("34", $_SESSION['wishList'][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try an alternative way like

```
<?php

$p_id = "34" // for try
$p_id = intval(34); // for try also

if(in_array($p_id, array_values($_SESSION['wishList']))) {
    // Product Id found in your wishList
}

?>
```

It will works only for single dimension `array`. For multidimensional use `foreach` loop.