# PHP Multi-Dimensional array search (with array_search)

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search), but I have an additional one to search for an array-key. Take a look at this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Text 1"
    ["types"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Level 1"
      [1]=>
      string(14) "something else"
      [2]=>
      string(15) "whatisearchfor1"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Text 2"
    ["types"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Level 2"
      [1]=>
      string(14) "something else"
      [2]=>
      string(15) "whatisearchfor2"
    }
  }
}
```

[This snippet](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.array-search.php#116635)...

```
echo array_search("Text 2", array_column($response, "name"));
```

...gives me a 1 for the second array-key, in which the term was found.

**But how do I receive the *global* array-key (0 or 1), if I search for *whatisearchfor2*, which is stored in the multi-array "types"?**

```
echo array_search("whatisearchfor2", array_column($response, "types"));
```

...doesn't work.

Comment: you can  `var_dump(array_column($response,'types'))` for get output array this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `array_column($response, "types")` will return an array of arrays. But to get *"global array-key (0 or 1), if you search for whatisearchfor2"* use the following approach with `array_walk`:

```
$key = null; // will contain the needed 'global array-key' if a search was successful
$needle = "whatisearchfor2"; // searched word

// assuming that $arr is your initial array
array_walk($arr, function ($v,$k) use(&$key, $needle){
    if (in_array($needle, $v['types'])){
        $key = $k;
    }
});

var_dump($key);    // outputs: int(1)
```

Comment: I also found out, that `array_search("whatisearchfor2", array_column(array_column($response, "types"), 0));` is working, too. What is better or more efficient?