# Get an array from multidimensional by a value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, php-5.5

I have a question. Suppose I have an array like this :

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
       (
          [id] => 4
          [name] => test
          [surname] => test1
       )
   [1] => Array
       (
           [id] => 6
           [name] => test4
           [surname] => test5
       )
)
```

I need to get all data for array by `id`. So for example if I want to get data for `id=4` I need to get an array like this :

```
Array
 (
    [id] => 4
    [name] => test
    [surname] => test1
 )
```

I tried with `array_column` but not work. Please help me

Comment: *I tried with array_column* Show that code. You are probably closer to the solution than you think.

Comment: Right, You are near to your destination.

Comment: @HareaCosticla, Your answer is ready at [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37156500/get-an-array-from-multidimensional-by-a-value/37156674#37156620)

Comment: Here you have some answers on how to search the id, then you can get the rest... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search/24527099#24527099

Answer (score 0):

With help of [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) & [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$array = array
(
   '0' => array
       (
          'id' => 4,
          'name' => 'test',
          'surname' => 'test1',
       ),
   '1' => array
       (
           'id' => 6,
           'name' => 'test4',
           'surname' => 'test5',
       )
);    
// Create array as id as index
$temp = array_combine(array_column($array, 'id'), $array);
// get the sub array
$new = $temp[4];
var_dump($new);
```

Another simple way would be -

```
$new = array();

foreach($array as &$v) {
    if($v['id'] == 4) {
        $new = $v;
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($new);
```

**Output**

```
array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(4)
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["surname"]=>
  string(5) "test1"
}
```

Comment: why with reference? And a break would be good.

Comment: @KiwiJuicer Thanks for `break`!! :)

Comment: @Sougata, What can i say about you? You make an answer and then mark this as duplicate!!!

Comment: @FrayneKonok Anything wrong with that?

Comment: No, nothing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You should need to have a loop and checking if the id of the sub array is your searching `id` or not, if it is then store then sub array and break.

```
$arr = array(
           array('id' => 4, 'name' => 'test', 'surname' => 'test1'),
           array('id' => 6, 'name' => 'test4', 'surname' => 'test5')
        );

$id = 4;
$out = array();
foreach($arr as $val){
    if($val['id'] == $id){
        $out = $val;
        break;
    }

}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
```

Check this out: [Online check](https://3v4l.org/fTllp)