# Find element in dynamic array

Tags: php, arrays

The array:

```
Array(   
    [0] => Array(         
        [0] => Array(
            [type] => CHAMPION_KILL
            [timestamp] => 888477
            [position] => Array(
                    [x] => 3001
                    [y] => 13152
                )
            [killerId] => 5
            [victimId] => 6
            [assistingParticipantIds] => Array(
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 4
                )
             )

        [1] => Array(
            [type] => ITEM_PURCHASED
            [timestamp] => 2357
            [participantId] => 10
            [itemId] => 3303
        )

    )
    [1] => Array(         
        [0] => Array(
            [type] => CHAMPION_KILL
            [timestamp] => 889522
            [position] => Array(
                [x] => 13123
                [y] => 4564534
            )

            [killerId] => 1
            [victimId] => 4
            [assistingParticipantIds] => Array(
                [0] => 8
                [1] => 2
            )
        )

        [1] => Array(
            [type] => ITEM_PURCHASED
            [timestamp] => 2507
            [participantId] => 8
            [itemId] => 4750
        )
    )
)
```

What i want to do:

```
Array(   
    [0] => Array(
        [type] => CHAMPION_KILL
        [timestamp] => 888477
        [position] => Array(
            [x] => 3001
            [y] => 13152
        )
        [killerId] => 5
        [victimId] => 6
        [assistingParticipantIds] => Array(
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 4
        )
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [type] => CHAMPION_KILL
        [timestamp] => 889522
        [position] => Array(
            [x] => 13123
            [y] => 4564534
        )

        [killerId] => 1
        [victimId] => 4
        [assistingParticipantIds] => Array(
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 2
        )
    )
)
```

I want to make an array including all arrays that has `[type] => CHAMPION_KILL`. But it must be dynamic because the main array will not always be same. So 
`$resultarray= array_merge($array[0][0],$array[1][0]);` wont work.

Comment: so loop on the main array, test that `type` field on each iteration, and save the ones you want.

Comment: @MarcB can you give me a example code or something? how can i test "type" field on each iteration?

Comment: `foreach(...) { if ($element['type'] == 'champion']) { $data[] = $element }`

Comment: Undefined index: type in if ($element['type'] == 'champion'])  line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP multi dimensional array search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through your array and search what you want:

```
$resultArray = array();
foreach($yourMainArray as $arrays) {
  if (is_array($arrays)) {
    foreach($arrays as $array) {
      if (isset($array['type']) && $array['type'] == 'CHAMPION_KILL') {
        $resultArray[] = $array;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get Notice: Undefined index: type and
 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

notice: undefined index is in   if ($array['type'] == 'CHAMPION_KILL') { line.
warning is in   foreach ($arrays as $array) { line

Comment: You're 1 array to deep. The second foreach isn't needed

Comment: Nope, there should be 2 foreach. Look at data. maybe not always there is `type` index? If not always change it into: `if (isset($array['type']) && $array['type'] == 'CHAMPION_KILL') `

Comment: @nospor Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() #in 2nd foreach line

Comment: I'm sorry, you're correct. Was looking at the second code example. in that case a simple `isset` should indeed do the trick :D

Comment: @YusufDevranlı I've updated my answer. You really have strange your data

Comment: @Mathlight im getting  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in second foreach line help.

Comment: @nospor oh i found out why that wasnt working. in original code it was more deep in arrays. so i added more foreachs and it worked. your solution was right for the array i wrote there. i didnt wrote the actual array because it is very huge. thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you iterate through the array and check if the childs meet the criteria.

Example:

```
$resultArray = [];

// Iterates through the main array
foreach ($mainArray as $secondaryArray) {

    // Verifies if it has the right structure
    if (is_array($secondaryArray)) {

        // Iterates through the secondary arrays
        foreach ($secondaryArray as $finalArray) {

            // Checks if the 'type' key exists and if the value is the one you want
            if (array_key_exists('type', $finalArray) && 'CHAMPION_KILL' === $finalArray['type']) {

                // Add the array you need to the array result
                array_push($resultArray, $finalArray);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You just have to replace $mainArray with the one you want.
And $resultArray will be what you expect.

You can check a code snippet here: [PHPFiddle Code](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/qbiz-vpjr)