# How Can I Select Data by Name From Array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array(
    [0]=>Array([uploaderName]=>x[uploadedImageName]=>k6gIjfO[uploaderIp]=>195.155.116.217[uploader]=>e0699587cbfd[uploadedServer]=>alpha)
    [1]=>Array([uploaderName]=>x[uploadedImageName]=>byUTyJo[uploaderIp]=>195.155.116.217[uploader]=>e0699587cbfd[uploadedServer]=>alpha)
    [2]=>Array([uploaderName]=>x[uploadedImageName]=>oSVEnNk[uploaderIp]=>195.155.116.217[uploader]=>e0699587cbfd[uploadedServer]=>alpha)
    [3]=>Array([uploaderName]=>x[uploadedImageName]=>Dj7GRYS[uploaderIp]=>195.155.116.217[uploader]=>e0699587cbfd[uploadedServer]=>alpha)
    [4]=>Array([uploaderName]=>x[uploadedImageName]=>upsb8IC[uploaderIp]=>195.155.116.217[uploader]=>e0699587cbfd[uploadedServer]=>alpha)
    [5]=>Array([uploaderName]=>x[uploadedImageName]=>YoEEzGi[uploaderIp]=>195.155.116.217[uploader]=>e0699587cbfd[uploadedServer]=>alpha)
    [6]=>Array([uploaderName]=>x[uploadedImageName]=>st3dLNs[uploaderIp]=>195.155.116.217[uploader]=>e0699587cbfd[uploadedServer]=>alpha)
    [7]=>Array([uploaderName]=>x[uploadedImageName]=>LBNpiIG[uploaderIp]=>195.155.116.217[uploader]=>e0699587cbfd[uploadedServer]=>alpha)
    [8]=>Array([uploaderName]=>x[uploadedImageName]=>mFYDmBG[uploaderIp]=>195.155.116.217[uploader]=>e0699587cbfd[uploadedServer]=>alpha)
    [9]=>Array([uploaderName]=>x[uploadedImageName]=>z03kSx1[uploaderIp]=>195.155.116.217[uploader]=>e0699587cbfd[uploadedServer]=>alpha)
)
```

I want to get any image's data from this array.

Example: When user shows `uploadedImageName == jCPjeWv`, I wan't to get who is it's uploader.

Comment: Related: [PHP multidimensional array search by value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6661530/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, just use `foreach`

```
$arr = array(/* content here */);

foreach($arr as $value){
    if($value['uploadedImageName'] == 'jCPjeWv'){
        echo $value['uploaderName'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's another way:

```
echo array_column($array, 'uploaderName', 'uploadedImageName')['jCPjeWv'];
```

- Get an array of `uploaderName` with the index set to `uploadedImageName`
- Access the index using the `uploadedImageName` 'jCPjeWv'

Obviously to do it multiple times you would want to actually create a new array:

```
$images = array_column($array, 'uploaderName', 'uploadedImageName');
echo $images['jCPjeWv'];
```

If you want to access the other values as well, then use `null` instead of `uploaderName`:

```
$images = array_column($array, null, 'uploadedImageName');
echo $images['jCPjeWv']['uploaderName'];
echo $images['jCPjeWv']['uploaderIp'];
```

NOTE: These ways only work if the `uploadedImageName` is unique.

Comment: Good trick. Doesn't it take too much resources from the server (Memory/Processing)?

Comment: @CarlosCarucce:  Doubt it, but added a reusable example.

Comment: To clarify for researchers, using a `break` -able `foreach()` will likely perform better than functional-style approaches (`array_column()` and `array_filter()`) because `foreach()` has the potential to stop iterating as soon as it finds a match. Conversely, functional iterators cannot stop when a match is found -- they will unconditionally iterarate the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

A foreach is possible, but I think it's important to learn the array functions as well so I'm just going to put this example here.

```
$uploadedImageName = 'jCPjeWv';
$filtered = array_filter($array, function($value) use ($uploadedImageName) {
   return ($value['uploadedImageName'] == $uploadedImageName);
});
```

This will return a `$filtered` with the other arrays removed since their `$value['uploadedImageName']` will not equal `$uploadedImageName`.

For more info check out the http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php manual.

Comment: To clarify for researchers, using a `break` -able `foreach()` will likely perform better than functional-style approaches (`array_column()` and `array_filter()`) because `foreach()` has the potential to stop iterating as soon as it finds a match. Conversely, functional iterators cannot stop when a match is found -- they will unconditionally iterarate the entire array.

Comment: Yes that is true, most languages have a concept of a "first" or "single" match filter, but it's been a while since I've used PHP, I can't recall if that type of function exists natively.