# Search for array row with specific column value and return another value from qualifying row

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering

I have a multidimensional array that I am trying to search for a specific value (`url`) and then retrieve an another value in the same row (`value`). I also need to divert to an else if it is not found.

```
array(2) { 
  [0]=> array(2) { 
    ["url"]=> string(7) "fareham" 
    ["value"]=> string(7) "Fareham" 
  } 
  
 [1]=> array(2) { 
    ["url"]=> string(11) "southampton" 
    ["value"]=> string(11) "Southampton" 
  } 
}
```

I have been experimenting with `array_key_exists()` and `isset()` to check it's set and just coming up `null`!

For example, if I search for `fareham`, I want to return `Fareham`. If I search for `nottingham`, I expect `null`.

How can I isolate the qualifying value?

Comment: [How Can I Select Data by Name From Array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37797178/2943403)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to index the data by the url columns and then use `isset()` to check if the value is there...

```
$data = array_column($data, "value", "url");
$search = 'southampton';

$value = isset($data[$search])?$data[$search]:"not found";

echo $value;
```

or for PHP 7+, you can use the [null coalescing operator (??)](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

```
$value = $data[$search]??"not found";
```

Comment: Man I always forget about the 3rd argument for array column, lol

Comment: Here I shortened it for you (in PHP7) `echo  array_column($a, "value", "url")['southampton'] ?? "not found";`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the minimal way to do it (no checks)

```
$a = array (
    0 => 
    array (
        "url" => 'fareham',
        "value" => 'Fareham'
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
        "url" => 'southampton',
        "value" => 'Southampton'
    )
);

$u = 'fareham';
$i = $a[false===($f=array_search($u,array_column($a,'url')))?-1:$f]['value'];
print_r($i);
```

Output

```
Fareham
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bf793a114c8d79463d8b364e57fea3c0b1b1454)

**How it works**

First we create an array we can search by using array_column on the column we want to search in this case `url`.  It looks like this `[0=>'fareham', 1=>'southampton']`

Then we use the normal array_search which returns an index, if you notice above the indexes are correlated to the original array.  Which means we can put that in as the top level key, then it's a simple matter of adding the key we want.

Because array_search can return a boolean(false) which PHP sees as 0 or the first index I put a little hack in for that.  But a better way is to check it like this:
    $a = array (
        0 => 
        array (
            "url" => 'fareham',
            "value" => 'Fareham',
            "extra" => 'Foo'
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
            "url" => 'southampton',
            "value" => 'Southampton',
            "extra" => 'Bar'
        )
    );

```
function serchMultiDimensionalValue($needle, $haystack, $fields='value'){
   if(false === ($f=array_search($needle,array_column($haystack,'url')))) return false; //or return [];

   if(!is_array($fields)) $fields = [$fields];

   return array_intersect_key($haystack[$f], array_flip($fields));
}


var_dump(serchMultiDimensionalValue('foo',$a));
var_dump(serchMultiDimensionalValue('fareham',$a));
var_dump(serchMultiDimensionalValue('fareham',$a, 'extra'));
var_dump(serchMultiDimensionalValue('fareham',$a, ['extra','url']));
```

Ouput

```
bool(false)
array(1) {
  ["value"]=>
  string(7) "Fareham"
}
array(1) {
  ["extra"]=>
  string(3) "Foo"
}
array(2) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(7) "fareham"
  ["extra"]=>
  string(3) "Foo"
}
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5dd1f50b48dac72ddacf68d89d16ff259327e1b9)

I added a bit more "functionality" to it, hope you don't mind.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f6970c807d1227f803fc8c2fe7070da232a4c0d

Comment: `no checks` - means it's not checking for boolean false.

Comment: There I fixed it for you ... :-/  I was thinking of Javascript because that returns -1 for missing items. ... lol

Answer (score 0):

While it might be alluring to seek out a one-liner like:

```
array_column($array, $returnColumn, $haystackColumn)[$needle] ?? null
```

Be aware that `array_column()` will be unconditionally doubling the memory usage (because it is generating a new array with the same length as the original) for the sake of assigning new first level keys to search by.

Metaphorically speaking, it is like building a new registry of residences in a neighborhood including every homeowner's name and their address. Yes, you can find out who lives at a given home  without knocking on the front door, but you had to knock on every door to collect every home's details before enjoying this convenience. Why not just knock on the door of each original house and ask if they are who you are looking for? It is much easier, and you will be able to "quit" early as soon as you find the homeowner that you are looking for.

For best efficiency and for least memory usage, I recommend the below classic loop with conditional `break`.  It is built with dynamic search and return variables for general usage, but you can use hardcoded values if you like.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ql05h))

```
$array = [
    ["url" => 'fareham', "value" => 'Fareham'],
    ["url" => 'southampton', "value" => 'Southampton']
];
$needle = 'fareham';
$haystackColumn = 'url';
$returnColumn = 'value';

$value = null;
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if ($row[$haystackColumn] === $needle) {
        $value = $row[$returnColumn];
        break;
    }
}
var_export($value); // 'Fareham'
```