# Load specific element by field name PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

Good day

below is my ARRAY output

how do i load the price of a SKU by name?

i need the price of *SKU* **PRODUCT1** for example which is 39.99
the array comes from a CSV which is converted to ARRAY

rough example

```
$SKU = "Product1";
$price = ['SKU']array; #somehow
echo $price;
```

Array output:

```
 array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "SKU"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "Product"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Price"
    [3]=>
    string(11) "Description"
    [4]=>
    string(5) "Image"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "PRODUCT1"
    [1]=>
    string(23) "Product Name stuff 1"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "$39.99 "
    [3]=>
    string(47) "desrption"
    [4]=>
    string(12) "product1.png"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "PRODUCT2"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "Product Name 2 stuff "
    [2]=>
    string(7) "$49.99 "
    [3]=>
    string(47) "product2descr"
    [4]=>
    string(11) "product2.png"
  }

}
```

Good day

below is my ARRAY output

how do i load the price of a SKU by name?

i need the price of SKU PRODUCT1 for example which is 39.99 the array comes from a CSV which is converted to ARRAY

rough example

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array is named `$a`, loop through each row and look for the SKU in the first column:

```
foreach ( $a as $row ) {
  if ( $row[0] == 'PRODUCT1' ) {
    echo $row[2]; // Price
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you what if more Rows are added?

Comment: returned null  foreach ( $a as $row ) {
  if ( $row[0] == 'PRODUCT1' ) {
    echo $row[2]; // Price
    break;
  }
}

Comment: @kmoser Please close questions which have been asked and answered before.

Comment: really wheres the answer that has these elements layout?

Comment: Duplicated answer here: [How Can I Select Data by Name From Array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37797254/2943403)

Comment: How Can I Select Data by Name From Array in PHP?  returned null