# How to join two php arrays using Ids

Tags: php, arrays

Please help me. I do not know what is the best way to data join these data with PHP code.

Here are my data.

```
ArrayA(array('id'=>'1','Date'=>'datehere'),array('id'=>'2','Date'=>'datehere'));
ArrayB(array('ArrayAId'=>'1','personal infos'=>'other data'),array('ArrayAId'=>'1','personal infos 2'=>'other data'),array('ArrayAId'=>'2','personal infos'=>'other data'),array('ArrayAId'=>'2','personal infos 2'=>'other data'));
```

I wanted to show all `ArrayA` items with their associate `ArrayB` Items as the following.

---

```
ArrayA-item1 

ArrayB item1 with ArrayA-item1 Id 

ArrayB item2 with ArrayA-item1 Id
```

---

```
ArrayA-item2 

ArrayB item3 with ArrayA-item2 Id 

ArrayB item4 with ArrayA-item2 Id
```

---

The thing is `ArrayB` includes around 100 rows for each row from `ArrayA`. 
So when I tried to get 50 `ArrayA` Items, `ArrayB` got around 5000 rows.

That is why I cannot use the following approach due to performance issue.

```
for(ArrayA)
{
     for(ArrayB){
          //Get all associate rows according to current ArrayA.

     }
}
```

The above code make my page dead because it have to loop 5000 rows for 50 times. 
So please help me and point to the correct direction to display all these data.

Thanks in advance. Kindly let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Can you show us both arrays with some actual sample data? The scenario you've mentioned above is bit confusing, with actual data we will able to help you better.

Comment: Provide some sample data.. And have you considered using in_array() instead of having a second loop?

Comment: @ShrikantMavlankar I modify the data abit more. Is it better?

Comment: @Prashanth  I haven't try that one. Will do it now.

Comment: @YoYo Try to maintain large array(Not too large) in in_array() for searching.

Comment: @YoYo Can't you modify your array structure to look like key-value pair?

Comment: If you are using PHP > 5.5.0 then there is one liner solution or else you have to create your own function which will iterate though both arrays. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieve to solve the problem with array_filter. 
I shared the code in case if someone encounter the problem like I do.

```
for($i=0; $i < count($mainArray) ; $i++){

    $currentId = mainArray[i]["id"];
    $output = array_filter($subArray, function ($value) use ($currentId) { return $value['mainId'] == $currentId; });

     foreach($output as $data)
    {
           //print data 
    }  
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of going for loops try array functions.

You could use array functions with callback such as `array_intersect_uassoc()` `array_combine()` etc..

Check PHP manual page on array functions.  You could craft your answer with these functions