# How to count multiple array values as per key in PHP?

Tags: php

I want count of email and comment_id as per id, like for id=>2 email_count=> 3, comment_count=>1.
Can anyone suggest how to loop or array function in php?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [email] => ronak1@xyz.in
            [comment_id] => 3
        )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [email] => ronak2@xyz.in
        [comment_id] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [email] => hitesh@xyz.in
        [comment_id] => 3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [email] => jayendhar@xyz.in
        [comment_id] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [email] => jayendhar@xyz.in
        [comment_id] => 2
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [email] => jayendhar@xyz.in
        [comment_id] => 4
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [email] => ronak@xyz.in
        [comment_id] => 1
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [email] => ronak@xyz.in
        [comment_id] => 2
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [email] => ronak@xyz.in
        [comment_id] => 4
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [email] => hitesh@xyz.in
        [comment_id] => 
    )

)
```

Comment: Sure, so what is your question? Please add the code you have so far if you want us to help with it. We are not here to make your work for you, this is not a free coding service...

Comment: using `array_search()`

Comment: read link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search

Answer (score 0):

It loops through the array and uses the email and comment_id as key. When a key doesn't exist it is created with the default value(0)

```
$comments = [
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'email' => 'ronak1@xyz.in',
        'comment_id' => 3
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'email' => 'ronak2@xyz.in',
        'comment_id' => 3
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'email' => 'hitesh@xyz.in',
        'comment_id' => 3
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'email' => 'jayendhar@xyz.in',
        'comment_id' => 1
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'email' => 'jayendhar@xyz.in',
        'comment_id' => 2
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'email' => 'jayendhar@xyz.in',
        'comment_id' => 4
    ]
    ,
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'email' => 'ronak@xyz.in',
        'comment_id' => 1
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'email' => 'ronak@xyz.in',
        'comment_id' => 2
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'email' => 'ronak@xyz.in',
        'comment_id' => 4
    ],
    [
        'id' => 6,
        'email' => 'hitesh@xyz.in',
        'comment_id' => 1
    ]

];
$emails = [];
$commentNumbers = [];

foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    $comment = (object)$comment;

    if (!array_key_exists($comment->email, $emails)) {
        $emails[$comment->email] = 0;
    }

    if (!array_key_exists($comment->comment_id, $commentNumbers)) {
        $commentNumbers[$comment->comment_id] = 0;
    }

    $emails[$comment->email] = $emails[$comment->email] + 1;
    $commentNumbers[$comment->comment_id] = $commentNumbers[$comment->comment_id] + 1;
}



var_dump($emails);
var_dump($commentNumbers);
```

result:

```
array(5) {
  ["ronak1@xyz.in"]=>
  int(1)
  ["ronak2@xyz.in"]=>
  int(1)
  ["hitesh@xyz.in"]=>
  int(2)
  ["jayendhar@xyz.in"]=>
  int(3)
  ["ronak@xyz.in"]=>
  int(3)
}
array(4) {
  [3]=>
  int(3)
  [1]=>
  int(3)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [4]=>
  int(2)
}
```