# Arrays comparison in php

Tags: php, arrays, performance, sorting, comparison

I'm trying to compare two arrays, and extract some info of one of them and store it at another array (3rd). The structure of these two arrays looks like this:

```
Array(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Id] => 123
        [Size] => small
        [Color] => yellow
    )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Id] => 456
        [Size] => large
        [Color] => red
    )
[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Id] => 789
        [Size] => medium
        [Color] => blue
    )
)
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Id] => 456
        [Size] => large
        [Color] => red
        [Available] => true
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Id] => 123
        [Size] => small
        [Available] => false
    )
[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Id] => 789
        [Size] => medium
        [Color] => blue
        [Available] => true
    )
)
```

In the example, I need to store the property "available" only if the ID of these arrays are equal.

**What I tried to do:**

```
for (var $i = 0; $i < count($arrayA); $i++) {
    if ($ArrayA[$i]->Id == $arrayB[$i]->Id) {
        $getAvailable = $arrayB[$i]->Available;
    }
}
```

**The problem:**

Since we can have the situation where the property id in array A, position 0 is in a different position in array B, which can have a different structure, I have no idea how can I access the information I need (available), from one array comparing the ids of ArrayB and ArrayA.

I am sorry if I didn’t explain it better, because it’s a bit hard to put in words this situation, but let me know if you have any questions, and please, help me finding a solution :)

**Desired array should look like this:**

```
Array(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
    [Id] => 123
    [Size] => small
    [Color] => yellow
    [Available] => false
)
```

Comment: whats the desired *new* array look like??

Comment: I edited the question and added this information in the end. @Dagon

Comment: ah ok, that makes sense. any change of getting ID as the key to start with? if not its loop on array doing a search on the other for each id

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search but it would probably be faster to loop the 2nd array first to use the Id as the key, then loop the first array

Comment: the problem is that if this array he mentioned has a lot more information than he put in the example, doing this loop may be too costly in terms of performance.. am I right?@Dagon

Comment: don't use `$ArrayA[$i]` since they won't lineup as usual, just use a simple `foreach`, then make an `if` comparison on the ids inside

Comment: Thanks for tip @Ghost ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr1 = array(
    0 => (object)(array(
        'Id' => '123',
        'Size' => 'small',
        'Color' => 'yellow'
    )),
    1 => (object)(array
    (
        'Id' => '456',
        'Size' => 'large',
        'Color' => 'red'
    )),
    2 => (object)(array
    (
        'Id' => '789',
        'Size' => 'medium',
        'Color' => 'blue'
    ))
);
$arr2 = array(
    0 => (object)(array
    (
        'Id' => '456',
        'Size' => 'large',
        'Color' => 'red',
        'Available' => 'true'
    )),
    1 => (object)(array
    (
        'Id' => 123,
        'Size'=> 'small',
        'Available' => 'false'
    )),
    2 => (object)(array
    (
        'Id' => '789',
        'Size' => 'medium',
        'Color' => 'blue',
        'Available' => 'true'
    ))
);
```

First: declare a new variable array which will later stored your new structured array

```
$newArr = array();
```

Then you loop your first array $arr1

```
foreach($arr1 as $row1) {
}
```

then inside first loop make another loop which find it's match id from the second array `$arr2` just compare there id and if it is match merge them

```
foreach($arr2 as $row2) {
   if ($row1->Id == $row2->Id) {
       // do something
   }
}
```

then push them but before you merge them you must convert them into an associative array

```
$newArr[] = array_merge((array)$row1, (array)$row2);
```

into your new array. and just stop the sub loop after you find it's match id using

```
break;
```

so your foreach loop would be like this

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr1 as $row1) {
    foreach($arr2 as $row2) {
        if ($row1->Id == $row2->Id) {
            $newArr[] = array_merge((array)$row1, (array)$row2);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will be inefficient on large arrays but ok for small one

Answer (score 0):

This is not efficient for a large array but here you go

```
function getEqual($arrayA, $arrayB){

 foreach($arrayA as $aIndex => $aData){
     $id = $aData['Id'];
      $aData['Available'] = false;

     foreach($arrayB as $bIndex => $bData){
         if($id == $bData['Id']){
             $aData['Available'] = true;
         }
     }

     $arrayA[$aIndex] = $aData;
 }

 return $arrayA;
```

}

Comment: What would be efficient then? Could you give me a hint about techniques? (btw - the last curly brace slipped out of the code block)