# PHP - Get key of Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
Array(
[32] => ki
[97] => Array
    (
        [0] => l$
        [1] => ml
        [2] => 8e
    )
[98] => fp
[99] => @w
[100] => lf 
)
```

if I do array search for example:

```
echo array_search("fp", $array);
```

the output will be "98". How can I get the key if im looking for a value inside another array like "ml"? I wanted to get "97" if i search for value "ml".

Comment: You would use a loop that would search each key for that value

Comment: echo array_search("ml", $array[97]); ?

Comment: Is that the last option? I mean, is there no any other functions that I can use?

Comment: well that's never been asked before in the history of the internet

Comment: array_search("ml", $array[97]), output is "1".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP multidimensional array search by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value)

Comment: "How can I get the KEY if im looking for a value inside another array like" oO

Comment: I wanted to get "97" if i search for "ml". Loop can make it but I am looking for other functions like array_search.

Comment: I don't think there are any, what's the problem with loop?

Comment: I just wanted to look for another solution. Anyway, thanks for your comments guys. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is such function for multi arrays

If you want to do it in a loop try:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    if(is_array($value))
    {
        $subarray = $value;

        foreach($subarray as $subvalue)
        {
            if($subvalue == 'ml')
            {
                echo $key;
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($value == 'ml')
        {
            echo $key;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write an alternate recursive `array_search` function like this:

```
function recursive_array_search($needle, $haystack, $parent_key = null) {
    foreach($haystack as $key => $value) {
        $current_key = $parent_key ? $parent_key : $key;
        if($needle === $value || (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle, $value, $current_key) !== false)) {
            return $current_key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And call it like `echo recursive_array_search("ml", $array);`

Based on http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#91365