# Searching in multi dimensional array using array_search

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with the following setup:

```
array(
 array(
  'product_id' => 733
 ),
 array(
  'product_name' => Example
 )
)
```

I want to check that 733 exists in my array which I need to use array_search (going by googling) as in_array doesn't work on m-d arrays.

My code is:

```
$key = array_search( '733', array_column( $items, 'product_id' ) );
```

If I `var_dump` the `$items` array I can see the `product_id`

I want to check the specific ID exists in the array and then perform other code.

Comment: try this solution ==> https://stackoverflow.com/a/6661561/1969866

Comment: you can check it like this:- https://eval.in/805046

Comment: try `array_values` function https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_values.asp

Comment: you can try in_array with array_column. have a look at https://3v4l.org/OOoYd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want to check that given product-id exist in your multidimensional array or not?

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php

$items = array(
 array(
  'product_id' => 733
 ),
 array(
  'product_name' => Example
 )
);
function searchForId($id, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if (!empty($val['product_id']) && $val['product_id'] == $id) {
           return "true"; // or return key according to your wish
       }
   }
   return "false";
}
echo $found = searchForId(733, $items);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/805075

Reference taken:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6661561/4248328

Comment: was waiting for the minimum time to pass, now done :)