# How to check a value on multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm trying to check value on my cart in my codeigniter project, i have this array:

```
$cart = Array
(
    [547650d3bfb9bce7ea6d61faf312fa41] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1502369193000
            [productid] => Product 1
            [qty] => 1
            [type] => sales
            [user_id] => admin
            [rowid] => 547650d3bfb9bce7ea6d61faf312fa41
        )

    [7473a2e4d2e4150c7de11d201538e179] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1502369241000
            [productid] => SG KENNA
            [qty] => 1
            [type] => purchase
            [user_id] => admin
            [rowid] => 7473a2e4d2e4150c7de11d201538e179
        )    
)
```

What i need just, check inside array user_id = 'admin' and type = 'sales' are exist.

This is what i try but with no success

```
$type = array_search('sales', array_column($cart, 'type'));
$user_id = array_search('admin', array_column($cart, 'user_id'));
if($type AND $user_id){
  echo "exist";
} else {
  echo "no exist";
}
```

Update:
I use a loop like this and still no success

```
foreach ($cart as $item) {
      if ($item['type'] == "sales" AND $item['user_id'] == "admin") {
        echo "exist";
      } else {
        echo "no exist";
      }
    }
```

Comment: try using `in_array()` You can find more here : https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp

Comment: in_array can't be used on multidimensional array

Comment: did you trying looping though your array and then finding the element using `in_array`

Comment: Yes, I did. always return false.

Comment: OK check my answer as well as the working example

Comment: just update your loop

foreach ($cart as $key => $item) {

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP multidimensional array search by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
foreach($cart as $row) {
    if(!empty($row) && !empty($row['type']) && !empty($row['user_id'])) {
        if ($row['type'] == 'sales' && $row['user_id'] == 'admin'){
            echo "exist";
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
} 
if(!$found){
    echo "no exist";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `in_array` inside a loop:

```
$cars = array
  (
  array("Volvo",22,18),
  array("BMW",15,13),
  array("Saab",5,2),
  array("Land Rover",17,15)
  );

foreach ($cars as $key => $value) {

 if (in_array("Volvo", $value, TRUE))
  {
  echo "Match found<br>";
  break;

  }
else
  {
  echo "Match not found<br>";
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to do two subsequent checks, it's better if you filter the array and check the result's count. Here's an example of doing this by using an anonymous (lambda) function:

Given that your array is `$arr`:

```
$results = array_filter( $arr, function ($entry) {
    return $entry['type'] === 'sales' && $entry['user_id'] === 'admin';
});
```

then you can check your `$results` array `echo count($results) ? 'exists' : 'does not exist';`

**Edit:**

You can also check for `isset($entry['type']) && isset($entry['user_id'])` for extra safety in the closure

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code, which will return an `array` of results that match the given conditions. Of course, you can return an entire array or some value or whatever you want. You can change and tweak it to your needs:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    '547650d3bfb9bce7ea6d61faf312fa41' => array
    (
        'id' => 1502369193000,
        'productid' => 'Product 1',
        'qty' => 1,
        'type' => 'sales',
        'user_id' => 'admin',
        'rowid' => '547650d3bfb9bce7ea6d61faf312fa41'
    ),
    '7473a2e4d2e4150c7de11d201538e179' => array
    (
        'id' => 1502369241000,
        'productid' => 'SG KENNA',
        'qty' => 1,
        'type' => 'purchase',
        'user_id' => 'admin',
        'rowid' => '7473a2e4d2e4150c7de11d201538e179'
    )
);

function searchInArray($array) {
   $returnArray = [];
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val['user_id'] === 'admin' && $val['type'] === 'sales') {
           $returnArray[$key] = $array[$key];
       }
   }
   return $returnArray;
}

print_r(searchInArray($array));
if(isset($array) && !empty($array)) {
     echo 'Found';
} else {
     echo 'None found';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check this using for loop , it will check your array data that user_id and type is match or not if match then $found true and break and if you want to check one of two is ok then use `||` condition

```
<?php
$cart  = array(
    '547650d3bfb9bce7ea6d61faf312fa41' => array
    (
        'id' => 1502369193000,
        'productid' => 'Product 1',
        'qty' => 1,
        'type' => 'sales',
        'user_id' => 'admin',
        'rowid' => '547650d3bfb9bce7ea6d61faf312fa41'
    ),
    '7473a2e4d2e4150c7de11d201538e179' => array
    (
        'id' => 1502369241000,
        'productid' => 'SG KENNA',
        'qty' => 1,
        'type' => 'purchase',
        'user_id' => 'admin',
        'rowid' => '7473a2e4d2e4150c7de11d201538e179'
    )
);

$found = false;
foreach ($cart as $key => $data) {
    if ($data['user_id'] == 'admin' && $data['type'] == 'sales') {

        $found = true;

    }
}

if ($found === false) {
  echo 'not found';
} else {
    echo 'found';
}

Output is : Found
```

hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try Out This.

```
    $Your_user_id = searchArrayKeyVal("user_id", 'admin', $YourMultidimensionalArray);
    $Your_type = searchArrayKeyVal("type", 'sales', $YourMultidimensionalArray);
    if ($Your_user_id!==false) {
        echo "Found user_id";
    } else {
        echo "Not Found user_id";
    }

    if ($Your_type!==false) {
        echo "Found type";
    } else {
        echo "Not Found type";
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this code to get the values

```
echo $arrayname['547650d3bfb9bce7ea6d61faf312fa41']['user_id'];

echo arrayname['547650d3bfb9bce7ea6d61faf312fa41']['type'];
```

Comment: As I understand from question, `547650d3bfb9bce7ea6d61faf312fa41` would be dynamic and will keep on changing. so you can't really hard-code it inside an array.

Comment: Yes, i dont want to echo the value, i just want to check if exist or not

Comment: i think it need to dynamic check

Comment: you can use my concept to setup a loop as well :-)

Comment: If i use a loop, it only catch the lastest array