# Check if value exist in array and get array from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have below PHP array:

```
Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( [policy_id] => 1 [category_id] => 5 [limit_amount] => 11.00 [limit_amount2] => 23.00 ), 
       [1] => Array ( [policy_id] => 1 [category_id] => 7 [limit_amount] => 32.00 [limit_amount2] => 23.00 ), 
       [2] => Array ( [policy_id] => 1 [category_id] => 4 [limit_amount] => 12.00 [limit_amount2] => 12.00 ) )
```

Now i want to do two things:

1. Want to check if `category_id = 7` exists in this array or not, and if it is there.
2. then i would like to get that complete array from this multidimensional array,

Example, if `category_id = 7` is in array then it should output

```
Array ([policy_id] => 1 ,
       [category_id] => 7 ,
       [limit_amount] => 32.00,
       [limit_amount2] => 23.00 )
```

I tried to use `in_array(`), but could not get required values,

Thanks for help,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP multidimensional array search by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) before doing the `array_search` (I assume your data is in `$array`):

```
$match = $array[array_search(7, array_column($array, "category_id"))];
```

If you need to first check whether the entry really exists, then first check the return value of `array_search`, and return something distinctive when the value is not found, e.g. `false`:

```
$index = array_search(7, array_column($array, "category_id"));
$match = $index === false ? false : $array[$index];
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) is available only in PHP 5.5 and newer.

Comment: ... and that all PHP versions up to 5.5 have [end of life status](http://php.net/eol.php), i.e. they are no longer supported ;-)

Comment: Sure, but no longer supported is not the same as no longer in use.

Comment: @trincot what if 7 does not exists in the array, this will always show the first item of the multidimentional array

Comment: @younes, I added the code to return `false` if the value is not in the array. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve your goal. This is a solution that uses [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$input = array(
    array('policy_id' => 1 , 'category_id' => 5 , 'limit_amount' => 11.00 , 'limit_amount2' => 23.00, ),
    array('policy_id' => 1 , 'category_id' => 7 , 'limit_amount' => 32.00 , 'limit_amount2' => 23.00, ),
    array('policy_id' => 1 , 'category_id' => 4 , 'limit_amount' => 12.00 , 'limit_amount2' => 12.00, ),
);

$categoryId = 7;
$output = array_filter(
    $input,
    function (array $item) use ($categoryId) {
        return $item['category_id'] == $categoryId;
    }
);
print_r($output);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [policy_id] => 1
            [category_id] => 7
            [limit_amount] => 32
            [limit_amount2] => 23
        )
)
```

The code above finds all entries from `$input` that have `7` in `category_id`, associated to the original keys in `$input`.

You can enumerate `$output` using `foreach ($output as item) { ... }` or, if you need only the first match you can get it using [`current()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php):

```
print_r(current($output));
```

produces:

```
Array
(
    [policy_id] => 1
    [category_id] => 7
    [limit_amount] => 32
    [limit_amount2] => 23
)
```

**Update:**

If the item cannot be found in the input list (f.e. when `$categoryId = 1;`), `$output` is an empty array (`array()`). It can still be enumerated using `foreach` but `current($output)` returns `FALSE`.

All in all, the code:

```
$categoryId = 7;
$output = current(array_filter(
    $input,
    function (array $item) use ($categoryId) {
        return $item['category_id'] == $categoryId;
    }
));
```

puts in `$output` the first item found or `FALSE` if there is none.

Answer (score 0):

With that problem u can use `foreach` array to check exists it!
I had make a function for that:

```
function checkArray($cat_id){
  foreach($arr as $index => $value){
    if($value->category_id == $cat_id){
      return $arr[$index];
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

if `$cat_id` exists return array u need, and if not exists return `false`

Comment: This is array of arrays, so you should check index, not object property: `if($value[$category_id] == $cat_id){ ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
$val = 7;
$key = 'category_id';

foreach ($array as $item){
    if (isset($item[$key]) && $item[$key] === $val)
            print_r($item);
   }
```