# get array from an array of array using value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of array like this

```
$data=array(
      array("9900","1","7"),
      array("9901","1","7"),
      array("9902","1","7"),
      array("9903","1","4"),
      array("9904","3","8"),
      array("9908","1","5")
);
```

I have value `9908`. When I search 9908 then the value  `array("9908","1","5")` should be printed. I have used `array_search()` but I have not got any success

How I can print the array after finding the value

Comment: This is a duplicate.  Please search SO before posting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value  this gets you the key to access the subarray

Comment: Your duplicate question is not crystal clear.  Are you only searching the first column values?  Will there be only one match or might there be multiple matches in the search results?  Knowing exactly what you are asking is important while searching for the best possible link to close this unresearched duplicate question with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
    $data=array(
      array("9900","1","7"),
      array("9901","1","7"),
      array("9902","1","7"),
      array("9903","1","4"),
      array("9904","3","8"),
      array("9908","1","5")
);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

    if( in_array("9908",$value)){
        $findindex = $key;
}
}
var_dump($data[$findindex]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var_dump($data[array_search("9908", array_column($data, 0))]);
```

To expand it,

> [array_column](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.array-column.php) returns the values from a single column of the input, identified by the column_key. Optionally, an index_key may be provided to index the values in the returned array by the values from the index_key column of the input array.

---

> [array_search](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.array-search.php) Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful.

**Edit:**

To add some control over it:

```
$index = array_search("9908", array_column($data, 0));
if($index !== false){
    // do your stuff with $data[$index];
    var_dump($data[$index]);
}
```

Dumps:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "9908"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "5"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this can help:

```
<?php
function search_first_row($needle, $haystack){
  $data = $haystack;
  $desired_value = $needle;
  foreach($data as $row){
    if($row[0] == $desired_value){
        return $row;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $data=array(
    array("9900","1","7"),
    array("9901","1","7"),
    array("9902","1","7"),
    array("9903","1","4"),
    array("9904","3","8"),
    array("9908","1","5")
);
$searchValue = '9908';

for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++){
    $innerArray = $data[$i];

    for($j=0; $j<count($innerArray); $j++){
        if($innerArray[$j] == $searchValue){
            print_r($innerArray);
        }
    }
}
```