# Trying to write a function for search a value in an array, relying on references in child elements

Tags: php, arrays, nested, parent-child

How can I achieve this behavior??
I've tried to write a function to implement this logic, but for some reason it does not work.
Here is the link that I tried to do http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/638fc7796a8918e2b7ef1469b746c29adba8d0cd

```
<?php

    $test = [
      'deepLink' => [
        1,2,3,4,5, 'testMe'
      ],    
      'base' => [ // child for (2 and target)
        'SuperMan',
        'deepLink'  // expected true, if we call array_search_for_target_key($test, 'target', 'testMe')
      ],    
      2 => [
        'base' // link on child (base)
      ],    
      'target' => [
        2   // link on child (2)
      ],
    ];

function array_search_for_target_key($array = array(), $targetKkey, $search) {
   $res = false;
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        if ($k === $targetKkey && in_array($search, $v)) {
              $res = true;
        } else {
           if (is_array($v)) {
               foreach ($v as $nested) {
                 $array =  $nested;
                 $res = array_search_for_target_key($array, $nested, $search);   
               }
           }
        }
    }

    return $res;
}

var_dump( array_search_for_target_key($test, 'target', 'SuperMan'));
```

So i soleved my problem, here the 
[link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7efd77c32aac2445f1f6d3237e5ec5ab88725f06)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP multidimensional array search by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value)

Comment: No, I rather need inheritance, a function that verifies that the value is in an array element, if not, then it looks further in the child

Comment: @AndreyGrodnov check my answer

Comment: @AndreyGrodnov Please post your expected result in your question.  What is the code logic exactly?  Does this even need recursion? or are the levels finite?

Comment: @mickmackusa See my answer to his question, he still not giving a feedback. I included the errors of his code.

Comment: I need recusion

Comment: Thank you all for helping, wrote what I need!
[view on sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7efd77c32aac2445f1f6d3237e5ec5ab88725f06)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error in this part

```
$array =  $nested;
$res = array_search_for_target_key($array, $nested, $search);
```

The `$array` is not an array so it throws an error. Which is

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

**So Change your code from this:**

```
foreach ($v as $nested){
    $array =  $nested;
    $res = array_search_for_target_key($array, $nested, $search);   
}
```

**With this**

```
foreach ($v as $nested) {
    $res = array_search_for_target_key($v, $nested, $search);   
}
```

After changing that we will encounter a new error

```
in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given
```

To fix this we need to check if the variable is an array.

**Change your code from this:**

```
 if ($k === $targetKkey && in_array($search, $v))
```

**With this**

```
 if ($k === $targetKkey && is_array($v) && in_array($search, $v))
```

Also in your:

```
if ($k === $targetKkey && is_array($v) && in_array($search, $v)) {
    $res =  true;
}
```

Change `$res = true` to `return true;`.
We don't want to continue if we already found the target.
Change `$k === $targetKkey` to `$k == $targetKkey`. `2 === '2'` will return `false` so change it to `==`

**Here is the Whole Code**

```
<?php

    $test = [
      'deepLink' => [
        1,2,3,4,5, 'testMe'
      ],    
      'base' => [ // child for (2 and target)
        'SuperMan',
        'deepLink'  // expected true, if we call array_search_for_target_key($test, 'target', 'testMe')
      ],    
      2 => [
        'base' // link on child (base)
      ],    
      'target' => [
        2   // link on child (2)
      ],
    ];

function array_search_for_target_key($array, $targetKkey, $search) {
   $res = false;
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
       if ($k == $targetKkey && is_array($v) && in_array($search, $v)) {
          return true;
       } else {
           if (is_array($v)) {
           foreach ($v as $nested) {
             $res = array_search_for_target_key($v, $nested, $search);   
           }
       }
    }
 }

    return $res;
}

var_dump( array_search_for_target_key($test, 'target', 'SuperMan'));
```

[Test here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5934315fc27564c98b7dc334d28b77aec15d07fe)

Comment: Thanks, but the result of the function returns false.
It turns out that the logic of the work is incorrect.
I need a value to be found via a link to key 2(
That is, for the value to be taken through key 2 from base!

Comment: @AndreyGrodnov okay so it wont work only in 2 => [
        'base' // link on child (base)
      ]?

Comment: @AndreyGrodnov I updated my answer. please change `$k === $targetKkey` to `$k == $targetKkey`