# get the specific value of a multidimensional array using a key

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I have an multidimensional array in which I want a specific value. For example I have an array for images like that:

```
[img_id] => 19, [crdate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00, [path] => /Media/19987245_10213822143447913_772090576_n.png,[tags] => funny
```

I want to echo the path of the image with the `img_id = 3`.

I thought something like

```
echo $array[$img_id -> 3]->$path;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP multidimensional array search by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value)

Comment: @iainn isn't there any way to get the path without searching the whole array? I was thinking since I know the id of the image i want i could write an echo like i echo a variable

Comment: If you want to search your array based on something, use it as the array's key. Otherwise, no, you'll need to loop over it. You can re-index an existing array using `array_column`, e.g. `$array = array_column($array, null, 'img_id');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need one liner, here is the one,

```
$name = $arr[array_search($img_id,array_column($arr, 'img_id'))]['path'];
```

`array_search` — Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful

`array_column` — Return the values from a single column in the input array

Here is working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83147dd519b2a877375984ea875e54e5ecee7333).

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the array with the help of `for-each loop` and check the value of `img_id` in `if-else block`. like below code,

```
foreach($array as $array1){

if($array1['img_id]'==3){
echo $array1['path']; // your answer
}
}
```