# Modify multidimensional array value from searching by key = value

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array, replace

I have an array here:

```
$records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'num' => 123,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
        'num' => 146,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 8,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Jones',
        'num' => 253,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 9,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'num' => 632,
    )
);
```

How can I search for ID 8 in array `$results` and modify the `num`? For example, find array that has ID = 8 and add 5 to the `num`? The the modified `$result` array will be:

```
$records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'num' => 123,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
        'num' => 146,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 8,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Jones',
        'num' => 258,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 9,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'num' => 632,
    )
);
```

Comment: you need to at least make an attempt

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value/46953625

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one liner trick will solve your problem,

```
$records[array_search(8, array_column($records, 'id'))]['num'] += 5;
print_r($records);
```

**array_search** — *Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful*
**array_column** — *Return the values from a single column in the input array*

Here is working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f4515e48d8bf06f70816afa5a501bd6578eeaa4b).

Answer (score 1):

**This is one way to achieve output**

```
$records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'num' => 123,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
        'num' => 146,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 8,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Jones',
        'num' => 253,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 9,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'num' => 632,
    )
);

foreach($records as $key => $value)
{
    if($value['id']=='8'){
        $records[$key]['num'] = $value['num']+5;
    }   
}
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($records);
    exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this one...

```
foreach ($records as $key => $value) {
    $search_value = "";
    $search_value = array_search("8",$value);
    if($search_value!="")
        $value["num"] = $value["num"]+5;
    $result[] = $value;
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

use `&$r` array is passed by reference so you can update the value in for loop without having the key

```
foreach($records as &$r){

 if($r['id'] == 8){
    $r['num'] = 258;
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
foreach($records as $key => $data) {
 if(in_array(8,$data)) {
  $records[$key]['num'] = 253+50;
 }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($records);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'num' => 123,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
        'num' => 146,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 8,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Jones',
        'num' => 253,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 9,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'num' => 632,
    ));



 $id2 = searchForId(8, $records);



function searchForId($id, $records) {
   foreach ($records as $key => $val) {
       if ($val['id'] === $id) {

           $abc = $records[$key]['num'] = $val['num']+5;
           echo "<pre>";
           print_r($records);
       }
   }
   return null;
}
?>
```