# How to check if value is in associate array?

Tags: php, arrays

With the following, I am pushing values into `$countries = array();`

```
array_push($countries, 
    array(
        'state'=> $state,
        'date'=> $jikuDate
    )
);
```

Then I need to do a check and I am doing:

```
if (in_array($name, $countries['state'])) {
```

How to check the value if its inside a multi level associative array?

Comment: you can use array_map() function

Comment: You have no choice but some kind of iteration over the array. Probably the easiest solution is something like `in_array($name, array_map(function($c) { return $c['state']; }, $countries)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP multidimensional array search by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value)

Comment: Although in the duplicate, I think the accepted answer is a bit out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `in_array` outright since it'll only accept a *flat* array. Just use `array_column` to get all `state` values, then make your checking.

Here's the idea:

```
if (in_array($name, array_column($countries, 'state'))) {

}
```

Basically, if your `$countries` are multi leveled, (meaning):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [state] => Arizona
            [date] => 2018-01-01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [state] => California
            [date] => 2018-01-01
        )

)
```

When you apply `array_column`, you sorta *pluck* out each `state` values, then gather them inside an array. It will yield an array like this:

```
array_column($countries, 'state') ===> Array ( [0] => Arizona [1] => California )
```

Only then you can use `in_array`. Just check out the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), its eloquently stated there very well.

Comment: yes works, just one last question if I might, trying to loop `['state'] ` the manual says `foreach ($countries as $cou => $value) { `but what is $value?

Comment: @rob.m you mean `$value` in `foreach ($countries as $cou => $value) {` ?, it contains each array inside `$countries`, if you mean `$countries['state']`, it should show an undefined offset since its not present there

Comment: exactly, how would we loop only on `$countries['state']` using that `foreach`?

Comment: @rob.m if you want to use a `foreach` to work on it, just use `foreach ($countries as $value) { echo $value['state']; // use this }`, it will correspond to the current iteration state value, you can try it if you want

Answer (score 1):

I use this code. The `has` function checks whether a given item or items exists in an array using "dot" notation.

i hope usefull for you :

```
function exists($array, $key)
{
    if ($array instanceof ArrayAccess) {
        return $array->offsetExists($key);
    }

    return array_key_exists($key, $array);
} 


function accessible($value)
{
    return is_array($value) || $value instanceof ArrayAccess;
}

 function has($array, $keys)
{
    if (is_null($keys)) {
        return false;
}

$keys = (array) $keys;

if (! $array) {
    return false;
}

if ($keys === []) {
    return false;
}

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $subKeyArray = $array;

    if (exists($array, $key)) {
        continue;
    }

    foreach (explode('.', $key) as $segment) {
        if (accessible($subKeyArray) && exists($subKeyArray, $segment)) {
            $subKeyArray = $subKeyArray[$segment];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

return true;
}
```

for example :

```
$array = ['product' => ['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100]];
var_dump(has($array,'ali')); # return false
var_dump(has($array,'product')); # return true
var_dump(has($array,'product.name')); # retirm true
```

Comment: thanks one last question if I might, trying to loop `['state']` the manual says `foreach ($countries as $cou => $value) {` but what is `$value`?

Comment: try it : `var_dump(has($countries,'0.state'));`