# How to search data from json array in mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql

```
{"email": "afadf%40gmail.com", 
"phone": "2525", 
"rooms": "4", 
"floors": "2", 
"user_id": "2", 
"ad_title": "sdafasfdasf", 
"features": "['Elevator','Center Stairs']", 
"car_space": "5", 
"full_name": "adaf", 
"sortOrder": "10000", 
"build_year": "2018"
}
```

I would like to searh data where features='Elevator' using above json format.

Comment: How is the JSON stored in the database?

Comment: And what version of MySQL are you using? Newer versions have specific JSON processing commands

Comment: This question is a little vague, is that data stored in your database or are you asking how to search a database using a term from the JSON? What exactly are you trying to do, what have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: php version is 7.0.30. and i want to search data from mysql.                                          like                                                                                                                           "SELECT data from properties WHERE json_extract(data,'$[*].features')='Elevator'

Comment: Even with JSON support in newer versions it's generally not a good idea to store unnormalised data in an SQL database.  Can you refactor the data into a structure that's more easily queried by SQL? (Hint: Dependant tables are usually how you deal with non-atomic fields)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `json_decode()` function. This function will return an array from JSON.

Ex:

```
$data = '{
    "email": "afadf%40gmail.com", 
    "phone": "2525", 
    "rooms": "4", 
    "floors": "2", 
    "user_id": "2", 
    "ad_title": "sdafasfdasf", 
    "features": "['Elevator','Center Stairs']", 
    "car_space": "5", 
    "full_name": "adaf", 
    "sortOrder": "10000", 
    "build_year": "2018"
}';
$arr = json_decode($data);
//The $arr variable will be an array contains the data from $data variable
```

Then, you can use `array_search()` function to search. Some references :

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value)

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_search.asp)

Comment: php version is 7.0.30. and i want to search data from mysql.                                          like                                                                                                                           "SELECT data from properties WHERE json_extract(data,'$[*].features')='Elevator'

Comment: The OP wants to only fetch records that meet a search criteria.  This will require you to fetch all records then filter them in PHP, which can get horribly inefficient very quickly for big datasets

Comment: Ok but can we search with in json array of mysql?