# PHP - Display Multidimensional Associative array using foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to understand multidimensional associative arrays. I need to have a list of information using an associative array and displaying it with a `foreach()` loop.

The list goes like this:

[image]

I got to the point where I have an associative array containing all the information

```
 $spellen =  array(
            "Game1" => array (
              "Amount of players" => "10 to 20",
              "Age" => "8+",
              "Price" => "€24,99"
            ),
            "Game2" => array (
              "Amount of players" => "2 to 24",
              "Age" => "12+",
              "Price" => "€34,99"
            ),
            "Game3" => array (
              "Amount of players" => "6 to 24",
              "Age" => "6+",
              "Price" => "€45,99"
            ),
        );
```

But how can I display this information using a `foreach()` loop so my end result will look something like this:

```
Game 1 can be played with 10 to 20 players, The minimal age is 8+ and the game has a price of 24,99

Game 2 can be played with 2 to 24 players, The minimal age is 12+ and the game has a price of 34,99

Game 3 can be played with 6 to 8 players, The minimal age is 6+ and the game has a price of 45,99

Game 2 costs 24,99

The game that costs 45,99 is called Game 3
```

Comment: Can you post some code which you have tried? The documentation of [`foreach(){}`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) has extensive documentation on the topic and the tutorials available on the internet are endless.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple.

Example:

```
foreach($spellen as $gameName => $value) {
  echo $gameName . "can be played with " . $value['Amount of players'] . " Players, the minimal age is " . $value['Age'] . "and the game has a price of " . $value['price'];
}
```

With foreach you loop through an array. The $gameName is the key, in your case "Game 1", and so on. The value is an array wicht contains all the values. You get them by `$value['valuename'];`

Comment: Thank you! I got the first part working. But what if I want to show the following:

"Game 1 costs 24,99 " or
"The game that costs 45,99 is called Game3"

This has to happen outside of the foreach loop. But I have no clue how to make that work

Comment: @RainierLaan Test the condition in the loop, and assign the array key to a variable that you use when the loop is done.

Comment: @RainierLaan This is different and depends on what exactly you want to do. You could do a array search and search for the game that costs 45,99, or you could select one specific game by name (e.g. `$spellen['Game 1'];` ) and then get all the values of it. Look at this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/6661561/9899193](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6661561/9899193)

Comment: @RainierLaan Where does `45,99` come from, why is that the one you want to print at the end?