# How to find array ID based on value

Tags: php

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the number of the array so I can I assign the proper salesman for the city selected? In this example I would want to get 1, since Ambler is the city I'm looking for.

```
    $cities = array (
  0 => array("Aldenville", "Analomink"),
  1 => array("Abington", "Ambler", "Ardmore", "Avondale"),  
  2 => array("Ackermanville", "Albrightsville", "Allens Mills", "Alpha"),
  3 => array("Adamstown", "Alburtis", "Allentown"));   

if (($key = array_search("Ambler", $cities)) === false) {
    echo "Not found";
} else{
    echo $key;
}
```

Comment: `$cities` is an array of arrays. `array_search` finds values directly within the given array.

Comment: `array_search` does not work for multi-dimensional arrays.  If you search for "search multi dimensional array", you'll find this is a duplicate.

Comment: are you missing closing braces ) for $cities

Comment: Every element in `$cities` is array - you want to search for "Ambler" for each array inside `$cities`

Comment: (NOTE: in the duplicate link above, I would recommend _this_ particular answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24527099/870729)

Comment: Try `array_keys()`

Comment: I was missing a closing ); So now I'm not getting an error, but how do I search through each sub array to get the key?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a search level. You made a 2D-Array of cities, but you're searching in 1D. When you search for a specific city, you have search for every (sub)array in the array '$cities'

Comment: Welcome. This should be posted as a comment (above), not as an answer.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how to do that?