# Search multi-dimensional array for specific key/value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array similar to this:

```
$arr1 = array(
        0 => array("departmentID"=>1,"userID"=>"3000001"),
        1 => array("departmentID"=>2,"userID"=>"3000002"),
        2 => array("departmentID"=>3,"userID"=>"3000003")
);
```

I basically need to search the array to see if a specific key/value pair exists.  For example, I need to know if department ID 2 with userID 3000002 is in the array.

I've tried this code:

```
$key = array_search('2', array_column($arr1, 'departmentID'));
echo ("The key is: ".$key);
```

This works fine but it's only a search on the department ID.  I need to know if the departmentID value of 2 exists with the userID value of 3000002 and I can't quite figure it out.

Would be grateful for any help!

Comment: what is your desired output? i hope this will help u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value

Comment: @devpro - Just a boolean would be fine in this case.  Just need to know if that specific key/value pair exists or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$key = array_search(array("departmentID"=>2,"userID"=>"3000002"), $arr1);
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you so much!