# Array search on manually generated associative array (different column names)

Tags: php, associative-array

Lets say I have an array like below

```
$array = array(
  array( //index 0
    'col_1' => 'one',
    'col_2' => 'two'
  ),
  array( //index 1
    'col_5' => 'five',
    'col_3' => 'three'
  )
);
```

Now I needed to search for the key value "three" and the output I want to return is 1 (array index). If there is no value exists, I want to return -1.

Actually the flow is,

- Search for the value, if exists return it's index. In my scenario the index is 1
- So that I can get `$array[1]['col_5']`

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value#answer-6661561), but in my scenario, the column names will be differ at any time.

For ex.,

```
$key = array_search('three', array_column($array, '?'));
```

In the above code, we need to specify the column name, but in my array, the column names are different.

Comment: Did you give a try to the first loop provided in the answer? This is certainly what you want

Comment: the problem I see in your question you are expecting index `3` to become index `1` for some magic reason

Answer (score 2):

```
function search($array){
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
    foreach($array[$i] as $key => $value){
    if($value=='three'){
        return $i;;
    }
  }
}

return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you are looking for, but here is some approach:

https://ideone.com/8S6445

```
$keys = array_map(
    function ($el) { 
        return array_search('three', $el) === false ? -1 : 1; 
    }, $array);
```

or probably you wanted something like:

```
$keys = array_map(
    function ($el) {
        $idx = array_search('three', $el);
        return $idx === false ? -1 : $idx; 
    }, $array);
```

I hope finally I've got what is your goal:

```
$keys = array_map(
    function ($el) {
        $idx = array_search('three', $el);
        if ($idx === false) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return array_search($idx, array_keys($el));
        }
    }, $array);
```

Even if I  understood your goal, I don't think that you really need to get index `1` instead of original key `col_3` - in most scenarios `col_3` is what you would probably use for the following calculations, and by the way same about transformation `false` to `-1`. So my guess the function you need should be just:

```
$keys = array_map(
  function ($el) {
    return array_search('three', $el); 
  }, $array);
```

It will return real **key** for associative array when element is found and **false** if not.

Or probably I still did not get your goal?

**UPDATE** If you just need one value do it straight forward:

https://ideone.com/odTCxI

```
$key = -1;

foreach($array as $k => $el) {
    if (array_search('three', $el) !== false) {
        $key = $k;
        break;
    }
}
echo $key;
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your response. Your code works fine. It returns array as a response. I just need index or -1 as response.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a customized implementation of the `array_filter` function. However, just using a `foreach``loop would be just as effective.

#### Example

```
$array = [
    [
        '1' => 'one',
        '2' => 'two'
    ],
    [
        '1' => 'five',
        '2' => 'three',
    ],
];

// Set our search parameter
$needle = 'three';

$searchResult = current(array_filter(array_keys($array), function ($a) use ($array, $needle) {
    return array_search($needle, $array[$a]);
})) ?: -1;

// Output
var_dump($searchResult);
```