# Search multidimensional array for value

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I wonder if there is better (faster) way to search for value in multidimensional array than looping through every item.

Lets say i have

```
$id_to_search = '16819976033';
```

And array which is pretty big

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => Array
            (
                [0] => 16771055710
                [1] => 16776555710
                [2] => 16819976033
            )

        [o] => 21566
        [p] => 12597.66
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => Array
            (
                [0] => 14089762
            )

        [o] => 12606
        [p] => 1747.49
    )
etc ...
)
```

I can find it if i loop through each item and than compare them but its very slow because array is big.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP multidimensional array search by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value)

Comment: What do you need to find, just the item exists or which element it belongs to?

Comment: @NigelRen Both.

Answer (score 2):

You can use by **array_search** function in PHP:

```
$key = array_search($id_to_search, array_column($YourArray, 'id'));
```