# comparator using array on php

Tags: php

I have some variable

```
$role = 2
$role_id = Array ( [0] => Array ( [role_id] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [role_id] => 1 ) )
```

for this comparator

```
 if (in_array($role, $role_id)){
    echo "Match found";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Match not found";
    }

**result Match not found**
```

I try with array_search()

```
 if (array_search($role, $role_id,true)){
    echo "Match found";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Match not found";
    }

**result Match not found**
```

how can I get value of role_id ?
thanks any help

Comment: Array search will search the top level array. If you have a compound array you'll need a deeper search. Take a look at array_column() on php.net

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP multidimensional array search by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$role_id` is a two-dimensional array. You need to search in the second, `role_id` dimension, which you can do using [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$role = 2;
$role_id = array (array('role_id' => 2 ), array('role_id' => 1 ) );
if (in_array($role, array_column($role_id, 'role_id'))) {
    echo "Match found";
}
else {
    echo "Match not found";
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/b3eEJ)