# Why is using array_search on multidimensional array is returning False, while the searched array IS there?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

My program's logic is complex, but I am facing problem in a little part, where I need to search for a key,value pair in a multidimensional array. For that, [I am using a combination of `array_search()` and `array_column()` functions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value#answer-24527099)

To demonstrate the problem, I have written the following little SSCCE.

```
$arrayOne = array ( '$oid' => '5e140f97e603f88ee52008ab' );

$arrayTwo = array ( 
  0 => array ( '$oid' => '5e140f97e603f88ee52008ab')
);

if ( array_search($arrayOne, $arrayTwo) ) {
    echo "True";
} else {
    echo "False";
}
```

**The output is always `False`.**

Now, since the key,value pair `$oid`,`5e140f97e603f88ee52008ab` IS there in $arrayTwo, so why am I getting `False` in output?

Comment: Try `array_search($arrayOne, $arrayTwo) !== false` as `array_search()` is returning 0.

Comment: @NigelRen I got it. Thank you so very much.