# how to search in Json and get sub data

Tags: php, json

i have a json file of users with all descriptions and its hard to find them with `data[2]`. imagine  in `data[0]->users->data` i have 3 user and i want to find `name = "Stafin"` to get `description->data->instagram` and get value. i'll give you a simple json data

```js
{"data":[
  {
     "id":1,
     "category_name":"Writers",
     "users":{
        "data":[{
          "name":"Steve",
          "id":"1",
          "description":{
             "data":[
                {
                   "instagram":"steveid"
                }
             ]
          }
       },{
          "name":"Stafin",
          "id":"2",
          "description":{
             "data":[
                {
                   "instagram":"stafinid"
                }
             ]
          }
       },{
          "name":"Sara",
          "id":"3",
          "description":{
             "data":[
                {
                   "instagram":"saraid"
                }
             ]
          }
       }]
     }
  }
]}
```

Code:

```
<?php
    $str = file_get_contents('http://localhost/json/test.json');
    $json = json_decode($str, true);

    function searchForId($id, $array) {
       foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
           if ($val['id'] === $id) {
               return $key;
           }
       }
       return null;
    }
    $id = searchForId('2', $json);
    echo $id;
?>
```

note that: answer it in php language
sorry for my bad English language. if you didn't get that, just tell me to describe more

Comment: Use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: i don't know how to

Comment: You right, I'm in learning with javascript, when it's done, I'll start php. Can you just help me with this :/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value

Comment: this is my foreach. but it's not working fine
  `<?php
   $str = file_get_contents('http://localhost/json/test.json');
   $json = json_decode($str, true);

   function searchForId($id, $array) {
      foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
          if ($val['id'] === $id) {
              return $key;
          }
      }
      return null;
   }
   $id = searchForId('2', $json);
   echo $id;
  ?>`
test.json is what i past it on top question

Comment: I thought you wanted to search for `name`, not `id`.

Comment: The array is in `$json['data']`, not `$json`.

Comment: sorry. i try'd it with other ways. i'll add id to the json in my question

Comment: But you still say **i want to find name = "Stafin"**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your function searches for `id`, but you said you wanted to search for `name`. You can make the key another parameter of the function. Then you can use it to find the `id` in the `data` array, and the `name` in the `users['data']` array.

```
function searchArray($searchkey, $searchval, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val[$searchkey] === $searchval) {
           return $val;
       }
   }
   return null;
}

foreach ($json['data'] as $data) {
    $user = searchArray('name', 'Stafin', $data['users']['data']);
    if ($user) {
        echo "Found Stafin";
        foreach ($user['description']['data'] as $desc) {
            if (isset($desc['instagram'])) {
                echo ", Instagram is {$desc['instagram']}";
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx, but i think you missed something:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\json\index.php on line 18`

Comment: I forgot the `;` on the return line

Comment: :| `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\json\index.php on line 12`

Comment: There's no id 2 in your data. I changed it to id 1.

Comment: please just test your code. `Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\json\index.php on line 13`. this is the line 13: `if ($val[$searchkey] === $searchval) {`

Comment: Will my problem be solved if I cry?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `$data['users']['data']`.

Comment: I'm just going by what you wrote in the question. You said to look in `data[0]->users->data`. `data[0]` is what you get when you search for `id = 1` in `$data`. Then I search for `name = 'Staffin` in `users->data`.

Comment: You could just use nested loops to search all the top-level arrays for `user = Staffin` in the inner arrays.

Comment: I've rewritten it to show the nested loops.

Comment: It's not tested. If it doesn't work, try debugging it yourself and let me know what I missed.

Comment: it's working just fine. Thank you for your patience with a newbie coder :)