# PHP multidimensional array search key

Tags: php

```
$list[7362][0]['value'] = 'apple';
$list[7362][1]['value'] = 'orange';
$list[9215][0]['value'] = 'lemon';
```

I want key for value 'orange'. I tried with array_search and array_column, but obviously I have issue array_column.

```
$key = array_search('orange', array_column($list, 'value'));
```

as described

[PHP multidimensional array search by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value/6661561#6661561)

but my case is slighly different. Key should return 7362.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php

$list = array();

$list[7362][0]['value'] = 'apple';
$list[7362][1]['value'] = 'orange';
$list[9215][0]['value'] = 'lemon';

foreach ($list as $keynum=>$keyarr) {
    foreach ($keyarr as $key=>$index) {
        if (array_search('orange', $index) !== false) {
            echo "orange found in $key >> $keynum";
        }   
    }   
}

?>
```

You can choose to just echo out `echo $keynum;` for your purpose.

Loop through the arrays and find out where you find `orange`.

You can refactor that a bit into a function like this:

```
<?php

function getKeys($list, $text) {
    foreach ($list as $keynum=>$keyarr) { 
        foreach ($keyarr as $key=>$index) { 
            if (array_search($text, $index) !== false) {
                return "$text found in $key >> $keynum";
            }
        }
    }

    return "not found";
}

$list = array();

$list[7362][0]['value'] = 'apple';
$list[7362][1]['value'] = 'orange';
$list[9215][0]['value'] = 'lemon';

echo getKeys($list, 'lemon');

?>
```

`echo getKeys($list, 'lemon');` will give you `lemon found in 0 >> 9215`.

`echo getKeys($list, 'orange');` will give you `orange found in 1 >> 7362`.

`echo getKeys($list, 'apple');` will give you `apple found in 0 >> 7362`.

Answer (score 0):

It's nested to far for the `array_column` at that level, so just loop:

```
foreach($list as $k => $v) {
    if(in_array('orange', array_column($v, 'value'))) {
        $key = $k;
        break;
    }
}
```

If there can be more than one then create an array and don't `break`:

```
        $key[] = $k;
        //break;
```