# Catch the array inside another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

Let me show you an example of what I'm trying to do. I got this:

```
$array = [
[
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name'  => 'Doe',
], 
[
    'first_name' => 'Johny',
    'last_name'  => 'Dow',
],  
[
    'first_name' => 'Johnys',
    'last_name'  => 'Doesnot',
], 
[
    'first_name' => 'Joe',
    'last_name'  => 'Dow',
], 
[
    'first_name' => 'Joes',
    'last_name'  => 'Down',
],
];
```

I want to catch the last array in which `'last_name' => 'Dow'`, and change all the data for this array (`first_name` and `last_name`)  and maybe add the `age`.

I think that `array_filter()` can be helpful in this case but I'm not sure how to deal with it.

Can someone guide me how to achieve this.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to edit always the last item of the array, or the item that matches some your rule?

Comment: no the item which matches my rule, which may be `first_name` or `last_name`. Catch that specific array and modify it

Comment: check this post to do your search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value

Comment: I know all about getting the specific value or key, but what I'm trying to say is to catch all the array which contains that key or value. If you can suggest me a solution I will appreciate it.

Comment: I'm sorry but did you read the post I linked? You are trying to get an array inside an array, and that's the post.

Comment: Yeah I read it and there is no solution about my question. There are just getting the specific value or key ecc. No solution for catching all the array which contains that specific value or key

Comment: not sure I understand what it is you need exactly, but possibly [this](https://3v4l.org/bHY2f) might help you.

Comment: thank you @berend, yes this is a good starting point

Comment: I just want to catch the last array /item and not all of them this is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: like [so](https://3v4l.org/TZC8N)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becase you want to catch the last item, so you can iterate from the end of array and then, break the loop after you catch the first item meets your condition:

```php
for ($i = count($array) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    if ($array[$i]["last_name"] == "Dow") {
        $array[$i]["first_name"] = "New First Name";
        $array[$i]["last_name"] = "New Last Name";
        $array[$i]["age"] = 111;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can iterate over the array with [array_reverse](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php). Setting the flag to true will preserve the keys, allowing us to access the corresponding item by its index.

```
foreach (array_reverse($array, true) as $index => $person) {
    if ($person['last_name'] == 'Dow') {
        // $array[$index]['first_name'] = 'some name';
        // $array[$index]['last_name'] = 'some name';
        $array[$index]['age'] = 25;

        break;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => John
            [last_name] => Doe
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Johny
            [last_name] => Dow
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Johnys
            [last_name] => Doesnot
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Joe
            [last_name] => Dow
            [age] => 25
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Joes
            [last_name] => Down
        )

)
```

Comment: This is a very beautiful solution bro! Thank you so much!