# php create an assoc array with customer_id

Tags: php

I want to create and php associative array from an array like bellow

```
 array:3 [▼
  0 => array:7 [▼
    "item_id" => "1"
    "customer_id" => "53453"
    "name" => "Item3"
    "price" => 0
    "quantity" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:7 [▼
    "item_id" => "3"
    "customer_id" => "53453"
    "name" => "Item1"
    "price" => 0
    "quantity" => 1
  ]
  2 => array:7 [▼
    "item_id" => "2"
    "customer_id" => "765656"
    "name" => "Item2"
    "price" => 0
    "quantity" => 1
  ]
]
```

I want to create an assoc with customer_id from this array like bellow. My goal is to create an assoc array with common customer_id for get all customer itmes.

```
 array:2 [▼
  // if common customer id, make an item array for the customer
  53453=> array:2 [▼
   0 => array:3 [▼
      "quantity" => "1"
      "name" => "Item1"
      "price" => 0
    ],
   1 => array:3 [▼
      "quantity" => "1"
      "name" => "Item3"
      "price" => 0

    ]
  ]
  78640 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "quantity" => "1"
      "name" => "Item2"
      "price" => 0
    ]
  ]
  
]
```

Comment: Why the final array doesn't the same keys (`quantity`, `name` and `price`) in each element?

Comment: Could you please share the code you already have?

Comment: @Syscall I have edited my question. please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `customer_id` using the same key, and and the old array without the keys you don't want.

```
$array = [
  ["item_id" => "1", "customer_id" => "53453", "name" => "Item3", "price" => 0, "quantity" => 1],
  ["item_id" => "3", "customer_id" => "53453", "name" => "Item1", "price" => 0, "quantity" => 1],
  ["item_id" => "2", "customer_id" => "765656", "name" => "Item2", "price" => 0, "quantity" => 1],
];

$finalArray = [];

foreach ($array as $item)
{
    $customer_id = $item['customer_id'];
    unset($item['customer_id']);
    unset($item['item_id']);
    
    $finalArray[$customer_id][] = $item;
}

print_r($finalArray);
```

Outputs :

```
Array
(
    [53453] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Item3
                    [price] => 0
                    [quantity] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Item1
                    [price] => 0
                    [quantity] => 1
                )

        )

    [765656] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Item2
                    [price] => 0
                    [quantity] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

[online example](https://3v4l.org/Upsjv)

Or if you only want the create some selected keys :

```
$finalArray[$customer_id][] = [
    'name'     => $item['name'],
    'price'    => $item['price'],
    'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
];
```

[online example](https://3v4l.org/eC0NW)

Answer (score 0):

```
$newarray=[];

foreach ($firstarray as $fa)
{
    $tarray=array($fa['qty'],$fa['name'],$fa['price']);
    $newarray[$fa['customer_id']][]=$tarray;
}
```

... and the result you want will be in $newarray, more or less.

Comment: but how if customer id is common?

Comment: my goal is to make and final which identify a customer have which items

Comment: From the snippet I posted the new array will be made up of arrays each with a key of the customer_id. Each array in that key will then be a full array with that customers items.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value might assist you without having to create new arrays. You can search within an array or arrays.