# search for a name inside array that it's inside array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to find a specific name given by user in this array if it's not found show a message. I tried but no result some help please.

```
<?php
$persons= array(
  array('name'=>'ADIANE','password'=>'adiane45'),
array('name'=>'ASABAN','password'=>'asaban23'),
array('name'=>'BENKASSOU','password'=>'benkassou67'),
);
?>
```

Comment: Your names all have a space at the beginning and end. Did you include that when you were matching against the input?

Comment: Show what you tried so we can tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: I have another question that says use function trim() to remove the space that's why.

Comment: If you do `if ($input == trim($element['name']))` that should work. What did you do?

Comment: for what I tried it's all wrong I used 'for' and 'foreach' and 'array_key_exists' and 'in_array' the problem is how the get in the arrays that inside the main array to try if name = the name that we looking for

Comment: I know about the trim() but first have to solve that one to pick the name that will apply trim() on it

Comment: If you want help, you have to show what you tried.

Comment: do I have to put all the wrong code that I tried and didn't work?

Comment: Post what you think is your best attempt.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value

Comment: even if it's wrong?

Comment: If it weren't wrong you wouldn't be here in the first place. But anyway, you can see the solution in the question I just linked to.

Comment: good point. thanks for help I will see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer thank you all for help.

$nameInput = $_POST['name'];
$passInput = $_POST['password'];

```
        $nameInput = strtoupper($nameInput);
        $c=0;
        foreach($persons as $key) {
            if($key['name'] == trim($nameInput) && $key['password'] == $passInput){
                $c+=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($c==1){
            echo "Bienvenue Monsieur $nameInput ";
        }else{
            echo "Votre login et/ou mot de passe n'est pas reconnu.";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, i hope this code will work:

```js
$x = 0;
$pSize = count($persons);

foreach($my_array as $number => $number_array)
{
    $x++;
    foreach($number_array as $data = > $user_data)
        {
            print "Array number: $number, contains $data with $user_data.  <br>";
            if (trim($data) == $userInput)
            { 
                echo "Found";
                break;
            }elseif($pSize - $x == 0){
                echo "Not found";
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is `$my_array`? Shouldn't that be `$persons`? And why do you have a nested loop instead of just using `$number_array['name']`?

Comment: And shouldn't `$data` be `$user_data`?

Comment: Thank you with this code I'm able to find the specific name but if I tried to find the name and the password of it I can't. by using '&&' in the 'if'

Comment: $x = 0;
$pSize = count($persons);
foreach($persons as $number => $number_array){
            $x++;
            foreach($number_array as $data => $user_data){
                if ($user_data == trim($nameInput) && $passInput == $user_data)
                { 
                    echo "Bienvenue Monsieur $nameInput";
                    break;
                }elseif($pSize - $x == 0){
                    echo "Votre login et/ou mot de passe n'est pas reconnu.";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }}`

Comment: this is the code that I used