# PHP changing value of item in a multidimensional array Without Key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am generating array like this

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [s_email] => amelia@example.com [s_inbox] => 0 [s_spam] => 10 ) 
[1] => Array ( [s_email] => claire@example.com [s_inbox] => 0 [s_spam] => 10 ) 
)
```

Later in my script I need to update  value of s_inbox and s_spam something like below

```
[s_email] => amelia@example.com [s_inbox] => 1000

[s_email] => claire@example.com [s_inbox] => 2000
```

I have searched some answers but most of are key based but instead here I want modify it by emails. Let me know if anyone here can help me for the same.

Thanks!

Comment: For each one you need to change, search by the email property value to get the index, then you know which index to update within. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multidimensional-array-search-by-value should get you started.

Comment: You didn't tell us whether the email addresses in the generated array are unique. They probably are, but we cannot assume that. If they are you don't have to (explicitly) search for the correct key for each row you want to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achived with `array_walk` method, it applies a callback for each item in the array.

Given the array:

```
$a = [ [ 's_email' => 'amelia@example.com', 's_inbox' => 0 ,'s_spam' => 10 ],
       [ 's_email' => 'claire@example.com','s_inbox' => 0, 's_spam' => 10 ]];
```

We want to apply the callback `update_s_inbox` for each item:

```
function update_s_inbox(&$item, $key,  $data)
{
    
    $email = $data[0];
    $s_inbox = $data[1];
    if ($item['s_email']==$email) {
        $item['s_inbox']=$s_inbox;  
    }
    
}


$email = 'amelia@example.com';
$s_inbox = 1000;
array_walk($a, 'update_s_inbox', [$email, $s_inbox]);
```

Probably the optimal approach if the emails can repeat.
If the emails are unique, it is probably better to put the email as array key.